# What is [] + [] in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What are the values of `[]+[]`, `[]+{}`, `{}+[]`, `{}+{}`? And how?

This my console log

```
>{} + {}
>NaN
>[] + []
>''
>{} + []
>0
>[] + {}
>[Object object]
```

Also

```
>var a = [] + {}
>a
>[Object object]
>var b = {} + []
>b
>[Object object]
```

How did the value change on assignment?

SRC: [video](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: those are just caveat's there aren't any design reasons for this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The difference for the `{} + []` is that when you do an assignment it is parsed in an expression context but when you type it by itself it is parsed as a statement

```
var b = /*an expression*/
```

This distinction is visible when using anonymous functions

```
//expression
var f = function(){}; //allowed

//statement
function(){}; //not allowed. function statements need a name.
```

---

So in the expression context, we add `{}` (empty object) and `[]` (empty list) with the [binary `+` operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1). Due to the [type conversion rules](http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1), `{}` is converted to the string ["[object Object]"](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.2) and `[]` is converted to the [empty string](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.2), the concatenation of which is "[object Object]" too.

```
//parenthesis force an expression 
({} + "hello")  //"[object Object]hello"
({} + [])       //"[object Object]"
({} + [1])      //"[object Object]1"
({} + [1,2])    //"[object Object]1,2"
```

Meanwhile, when we remove the parenthesis, the `{}` is parsed as an empty block statement. For pratical purposes it works as if we had commited it entirely, leaving an [unary `+` operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.6) to act on the list. This converts it to a number.

```
+[]     // 0
{} + [] // 0
+{}     // NaN
{} + {} // NaN
{} +"17"// 17
```

While it might seem weird to be able to get a value from a statement (instead of only from expressions), the Javascript standard, *does* [specify](http://es5.github.com/#x8.9) a value for a statement. In our case, our program is a list of two source elements, whose [value is given by](http://es5.github.com/#x14) the last statement, an [expression statement](http://es5.github.com/#x12.4).

A way to see the statement completion value in action is via eval:

```
 eval("{}")  //undefined
 eval("1")   //1
 eval("1;2") //2
```

Answer (score 4):

The `+` operator concats strings.  So it attempts to convert the objects and arrays to strings.

`{}` converts to `'[Object object]'`, and `[]` converts to `''`.

EDIT: I can't explain why `{} + []` is `0` and why `({}) + []` is `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: `{} + []` I'd guess that the `{}` is interpreted as an empty block statement, so the `+` is interpreted as the *unary* version, and so you're left with `+[]`, which does a *toNumber* conversion of the Array *(by way of a toString conversion)*.

Comment: am is correct; e.g. `{alert(1)}` will alert rather than throw a `missing :`