# In JavaScript, why do []+[] return empty string, []+{} return Object, {}+[] return 0, and {}+{} return NaN?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone explain these bizarre Javascript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/can-anyone-explain-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the-wat-ta)

Someone I know gave me these examples as a reason why he can't consider javascript a proper programming language, or something along the line.

I was wondering if there are some reasons for these return values?

For the first one, I guess an explanation could be, that `[]==""` returns true? And therefore `[]+[]` is 'equivalent' to `""+""`? But if that's right, since `[]==0` returns true too, why is the empty string interpretation chosen over 0?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/can-anyone-explain-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the-wat-ta

Comment: Not something, its like Duplicate²

Comment: I believe he's been watching this talk: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: Actually, `[]+{}` returns **string** with the content of `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Must admit I did not search prior to posting...