# Problems with adding object with array

Tags: javascript

Inspired by this [video](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat), I tested *further* with `{}+[]`.

**Test 1:**

```
typeof {}+[]  //"object"
```

Okay, so `{}+[]` is an `object`.

**Test 2:**

```
var crazy = {}+[];
typeof crazy  //"string"
```

What? Didn't `{}+[]` is an `object`? Why is it a `string` now?

**Test 3:**

```
console.log({}+[])
```

What I got:

[image]

So it is a `number`!... No?

So **what actually is the type of `{}+[]`**??

### UPDATED

To people who say `{}+[]` is a empty string:

```
{}+[] === ""     //false
({}+[]) === ""   //false
({};+[]) === ""  //SyntaxError
({}+[]).length   //15
```

JavaScript is so hard to understand...

Comment: I think in test1, typeof finds first paramater's type -> {}, and it's an object, try `typeof ({}+[])` this one, it's string.

Comment: @pcamal, So is it a number or a string? (Thought `{}+[]` would be `object`, because both of them are.)

Comment: Regarding your update: `{}+[] === ""` is evaluated as `{}; +[] === "";`, i.e. empty block and `+[] === ""`. `{}+[] === 0` yields `true`.

Comment: *JavaScript is so hard to understand*: Well, that's because you are ambiguous ;) When encountering `{}` in `{}+[] === ""` the parser does not know whether `{}` should indicate an object literal or a block. Since this is not in an expression context, `{}` is interpreted as block (the default behavior). The parenthesis `(...)` *force* an evaluation as expression.

Comment: Maybe you are right... `{}+[]===({}+[])  //false`

Comment: Yep, this is evaluated as `{};+[]===({}+[])` which ends up being `{};0 === "[object Object]"`. If you want to learn more about how the addition operator works,  have a look at the specification: http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1

Comment: @FelixKling - But why it adds `;` after `{}`?

Comment: I just added this to indicate that the line `{}+[]` is interpreted as two statements and not as one. But since JavaScript has automatic semicolon insertion it might actually do this. Why? Because if some syntax is ambiguous, a decision has to be made how to interpret it. In this case, the developers decided to interpret `{}+[]` as `block`, `unary plus`, `array`  and not as `object`, `addition operator`, `array`. You might not agree with this, but that's how it is :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Type of `{}+[]` may vary depending on the context.

1. `typeof {}+[]  //"object"`
   As per operators precedence in this case `typeof {}` evaluates to "object", `+[]` adds an empty string(array is coerced to string) therefore result is "object".
   You could think of checking `typeof ({}+[])` (your second case).
2. `var crazy = {}+[];
   typeof crazy  //"string"`
   In this case you are adding object and array - they both coerce to string, therefore `typeof` returns "string".
3. `{}+[]`
   This is interpreted as an empty block of code, unary plus and empty array.
   First part does nothing, array is converted to a comma-separated string of it's elements(empty string for empty array), then to a number(empty string is converted to 0), hence `0`.

**UPDATED**

- `{}+[] === ""     //false`
  see #3, `{}` is interpreted as a block, you are getting `0` on the left.
  Compare `{}+[] === 0 // true`.
- `({}+[]) === ""   //false`
  see #1, `{}` is interpreted as an object literal. When trying to add array and object, they both convert to string, `"[object Object]"` for object and empty string for array. Hence, you are getting `"[object Object]"` on the left.
  Compare `({}+[]) === "[object Object]" // true`.
- `({};+[]) === ""  //SyntaxError`
  I guess, this one is self-explanatory :)
- `({}+[]).length   //15`
  15 is exactly the length of `"[object Object]"`, see above.

Comment: @Derek: Because `+""` is `0`. @Li0liQ: Btw, the string is *not* converted to a number equal to the length of the string. `+"abc"` returns `NaN`. How the unary plus converts strings is defined in the specification.

Comment: Yep, and `({}+[])` in the console will give you object.

Comment: @Felix Kling Thanks for the remark, indeed, array is converted to a comma-separated list of it's values or empty string in case of empty array. Empty string is converted to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
var f = {}+[];
console.log(f==="[object Object]")
```

this will log `true` because when you assign `{}+[]` to the var it converts it to string by using the `toString()` method of it... which in this case returns "[object Object]" (which is 15 letters long - and that where the length=15 is from)