# How is the addition of objects in JavaScript carried out? What's going on 'under the hood'?

Tags: javascript

Recently I came across an interesting snippet of JavaScript.

```
 {} + [] = 0
```

Oops and the result is 0. How is this addition of objects being carried out? What's going behind the scenes? Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: and you'll be surprised what []+{} does ... actually , if you do var a={} , then a+[] you get a different result from direclty adding {}+[] .

Comment: exact duplicate of [Problems with adding object with array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376485/problems-with-adding-object-with-array) or better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the

Comment: see also duplicate [Objects and arrays addition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930644/objects-and-arrays-addition)

Comment: @Bergi +1 for that [second link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the) (in your first comment). Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

if you are useing chrome to execute the code, if so, V8 dynamically creates hidden classes behind the scenes [v8](https://developers.google.com/v8/design?hl=en)

Comment: I dont think it is chrome related , there is some typecasting involved , the question is what is casted into what.

Answer (score 0):

{} is equal to new Object() and [] is equal to new Array() but this is for declaration. When i addition {} + [] this, i am geting string "[object object]" and length equals to 15.Aslo i am using chrome.