# Odd addition behavior in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking through some old downvoted questions, and I came across [How to add 2 numbers in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049978/how-to-add-2-numbers-in-jquery), and I saw that:

```
$(1)+$(2)="[Object object][Object object]"
```

So then tried to see what `$(1)` put out, and it turned out to be `[1]`, and likewise for `$(2)` and `[2]`.

Normally, when you try to add `[1]+[2]`, it will give you `"12"`, but if you add `$(1) and $(2)`, it gives you `"[object Object][object Object]"`.

What is the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: You can find this interesting: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: `$(1).toString() === "[object Object]"`

Comment: [Blog post](http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html) related to that video talk. Also, [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376485/problems-with-adding-object-with-array).

Comment: That's because $(something) returns a jQuery object. If you did this: $(1)[0]+$(2)[0] you'd get the answer "3"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(1) might display in your console as [1], but don't be fooled, it's still a jQuery object, not an int in an array.

```
console.log(Array.isArray($(1)) //false
```

[object Object] is usually what displays if you convert any object to a string, so that's why it shows up as [object Object] when it's a string.

When you do the addition there, it probably first converts both of these objects to strings (because it doesnt know how to add objects) and then concatenates the strings.

Comment: `typeof [] // object` - `Array.isArray($(1))` might demonstrate your point better.