# When does JS interpret {} as an empty block instead of an empty object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebug

I was reading the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376485/problems-with-adding-object-with-array) (about the "wat" video) and it said:

3. `{}+[]`
   This is interpreted as an empty block of code, unary plus and empty array. First part does nothing, array is converted to a comma-separated string of it's elements (empty string for empty array), then to a number (empty string is converted to 0), hence 0.

I am currently learning JS from "The Definitive Guide" so I try to really understand things like that.

My question is, when does JS decide to interpret `{}` as an empty block of code, instead of an empty object?

Also, there are some inconsistencies between Node.js and Firebug which I would like to understand.

Firebug:

[image: Firebug console output for <code>{}[]</code> and <code>({}[])</code>]

Node.js:

[image: Node.js output for <code>{}[]</code> and <code>({}[])</code>]

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, in that it explicitly *references* the other question and asks about a detail.

Comment: @Pointy - It references a different question. The linked one clearly explains the behavior. As noted in the duplicate, [] and {} are both converted to their primitive values. `.join` on an empty array is an empty string. toString.call({}) is "[Object object]". Expressions cause concatenation, for example ("1"+0) = 10 or "[Object object]" + "" = "[Object object]"

Comment: @TravisJ I agree that it's a matter of opinion over whether it's really a duplicate. I don't have a big problem with duplicates, but I understand that others do so if you feel strongly about it go ahead and close it and I won't touch it :)

Comment: @TravisJ Also I didn't realize I had god-like powers to reopen without a vote :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Let's look at the language grammar, shall we? [Section 12, Statements](http://es5.github.io/#x12):

```
Statement :
    Block
    VariableStatement
    EmptyStatement
    ExpressionStatement
    ...lots of other stuff...
```

That's a very fancy way of saying that a statement can be a block, a variable statement, an empty statement, an expression statement, or lots of other stuff. Notice that the first option there is a 'Block':

```
Block :
    { StatementList(opt) }

StatementList :
    Statement
    StatementList Statement
```

Which is again, a fancy way of saying that a block is a `{`, optionally followed by a bunch of statements, followed by a `}`.

And that's what you see in your example: Before the JavaScript parser thinks that what you have could be an object literal (which is defined somewhere under `ExpressionStatement`, the 4th thing a 'Statement' could be), it first thinks that you have a 'Block'.

Edit: If you want, you can see it live in a JavaScript engine's source code:

- In V8, Chrome's JavaScript engine, we go into [`Parser::ParseStatement`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/3969195bb2e224db3bf60d3a1e9bf17ee1be88b8/src/parser.cc#L1572). The [first thing it checks](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/3969195bb2e224db3bf60d3a1e9bf17ee1be88b8/src/parser.cc#L1597-L1599) is whether we're on a `{`, and if it does, parses as block.
- In SpiderMonkey, Firefox's JavaScript engine, we go from [`Parser::statement`](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/78a4540b0a9c/js/src/frontend/Parser.cpp#l5413) to again see [the first check](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/78a4540b0a9c/js/src/frontend/Parser.cpp#l5417) being against a `{` and parsing it as a block statement.

Regarding your second question, that's been covered to great detail [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17268468/617762). To summarise in a sentence: Node.js treats your input as if it were an expression (thus it can't be a 'Block'), while Firebug/Chrome dev tools treat it like a 'Statement'.

Comment: I don't think it's correct that the Node REPL treats the input like an expression - you can type in a `for` loop in the REPL, for example.

Comment: That's why the summary is in a sentence. Benjamin Gruenbaum's answer goes into more detail: the REPL first tries to execute it as an expression, and if a SyntaxError is thrown, it goes to straightforward `eval`. Why? *shrug*

Comment: OK I see now - Node *explicitly* checks for the case of an object literal (leading `{`).  I don't think I'd do that (principal of least surprise) but whatever.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting references! I still don't understand why the semicolon in the Node.js example matters.

Comment: Well, a semicolon isn't allowed in an expression, so it'd fail to be evaluated as an expression and instead be evaluated as a statement.

Answer (score 2):

When the first token in a new statement is `{`, then `{}` is interpreted as an empty block.

(Actually of course when `{` appears after the header clause of something like `if` or `while`, then `{}` is an empty block too, but that's not the *interesting* case.)

Thus in any other context, like say an argument to a function:

```
foo({});
```

the `{}` is interpreted as an empty object literal.

This situation is similar to the way in which the `function` keyword is treated differently when it's the first thing in a statement. The syntax has ambiguity, and the parser solves the problem with fixed rules.

Comment: How do you explain the first Node.js example? Thanks!

Comment: @EllaShar I'm not too familiar with Node, but it basically just passes the string you type to `eval()`, but it does it in some way that alters the syntactic context. If you type `;{}+[]` in Node, then you get `0` like in Firebug.

Comment: Token parsing would do backtracking; why would {...x.d} === x.d not do backtracking to correct the evaluation that it is an expression, not a statement?

Would it lead to too many performance hits for parsers? It seems weird to leave such things in language unless solving these would cause a lot of pain.