# Using string interpolation for an object key in a gruntfile.coffee

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs

I'm creating a gruntfile.coffee for a project with a series of tasks. The format of some of these tasks is conveniently:

```
"path/to/dest" : ["path/to/src1", "path/to/src2"]
```

However, I'd like to save the directory names in variables at the top of the file, so a snippet of the gruntfile might look like this:

```
BUILD_DIR = "build"

...

files:
  "#{BUILD_DIR}/src/js/production.js": ["Thing.js"]

...
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> > Error: In /Users/me/path/to/project/gruntfile.coffee, Parse error on line X: Unexpected '{'

Is there something wrong with my syntax? I've seen this brought up [in their issues a lot](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+key+string+interpolation) and their [documentation explicity states](http://coffeescript.org/#strings) that they support string interpolation in object keys.

Answer (score 0):

The thing wrong with your syntax seems to be that you're using keys in an array literal, not that you're using interpolated string keys in object literal. Use

```
… {
  …
  files: {
    "#{BUILD_DIR}/src/js/production.js": ["Thing.js"]
  }
  …
}
```

Comment: One of the instances in my file is an array and the other is an object so it doesn't make a difference. I updated the question to show an object literal. Did you try this? Is there any particular reason you using the curly braces in coffeescript?

Comment: @AbeFehr: Yes, I did try this, it does work in the online coffeescript repl. Are you sure that you've got the latest version? If so, there might be a different mistake that is not related to the string interpolation, it would help if you could post the full code that produces this error.

Comment: I feel like this is a coffeescript issue. I just went to the repl and typed the following two lines: x = 5 and then { "prop#{x}": 5 }, which failed with the same error as mine. The line: { "prop5": 5 } succeeded though.

Comment: @AbeFehr: You'll probably have to use `({"prop#{x}": 5})` to make sure it's an expression - the old [block vs object literal problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26347326/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in CoffeeScript 1.9.3. From the [changelog](http://coffeescript.org/#1.9.3):

> - Bugfix for interpolation in the first key of an object literal in an implicit call.