# What do brackets really mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What could possibly be going on and what do brackets really mean when they change the object literal in this example

```
> {}
Object {}
> ({})
Object {}
> {}.toString()
VM7282:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

but...

```
> ({}).toString()
[object Object]
```

?

Comment: Just tried both {}.toString() and ({}).toString() in node.js.  I get [object object] for both.  How are you testing this?

Comment: @Sanjeev `{}` is a block statement, and then `.toString()` throws. I think node.js does some nasty conversion to expression under the hood, so that `{}` is treated as an object initializer.

Comment: Yes testing stuff like this in a developer console adds confusion if you're not quite certain what's going on - it's always better to write some "real" code for such syntax experiments.

Comment: Just tested it in chrome, Firfox, and IE with console.log({}.toString()) and console.log(({}).toString()), and still get the same result.

Comment: @Sanjeev Read [When does JS interpret {} as an empty block instead of an empty object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26347326/1529630). You are forcing it to be treated as an expression.

Comment: Very interesting.  Thanks @Oriol.