# Why {} == 1 entered in console throws error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Chrome console this `JavaScript` command throws error:

```
> {} == 1 // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==
```

This command does not throw any error:

```
> ({} == 1)?true:false // false
```

Why first command throws error, but second doesn't?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347326/when-does-js-interpret-as-an-empty-block-instead-of-an-empty-object