# {} - 0 VS ({} - 0) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

In the Chrome JavaScript console, why does wrapping the statement `{} - 0` in parentheses change the returned value?

```
{} - 0    // Returns -0
({} - 0)  // Returns NaN
```

It seems incredibly strange that wrapping a single statement in parentheses alters the contained value. What am I missing here?

Comment: Good question, sure there are others much much more knowledgable than me. I would guess it has to do with the fact that you're wrapping it in paranthesis, which makes it a self-executable function?

Comment: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: Seen as an empty block, vs empty object

Comment: @JoeHawkins Heh, I've seen the WAT talk before. It actually inspired me to play with some weird expressions.

Comment: On the one hand I want to +1 this... on the other hand I want to downvote it into oblivion...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two possible interpretations of the line `{} - 0`:

1. It can be interpreted as `{}; -0`, where `{}` is interpreted as an empty block statement, and `-` is the unary negation operator (so `-0` is just "negative zero"). The value of this when evaluated is the value of the last statement, which is -0.
2. It can be interpreted as `({} - 0)`, where `{}` is interpreted as an empty object, and `-` is the subtraction operator (so `0` is subtracted from `{}`).

In your first line, this is ambiguous, so it will choose the first interpretation. In the second line, the first interpretation is invalid (as a block statement can never be part of an expression, which you're forcing with the parantheses).

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Not OP, but I have a followup to this: what if you force the `{}` to be interpreted as an object by adding a method or property?  This works with the parenthesis but not without. (e.g. with parenthesis, this expression is evaluated to `3`: `({valueOf:()=>3} - 0)`, but without, it still returns `-0` in the console: `{valueOf:()=>3} - 0`).  Shouldn't the added method force it to interpret the `{ .. }` as an object at that point and then try to evaluate it as subtraction?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I think the same reasoning here still applies, without the parens, it can still be interpreted as `{valueOf:()=>3}; -0` however `({valueOf:()=>3}; -0)` is a syntax error.

Comment: @JosephMarikle You would think so, but no: `valueOf:` is in this case a [label statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) (a rare JavaScript feature), before the statement `() => 3;`, so it's still interpreted as a block statement instead of an object.
It's interpreted the same way as `{ valueOf: () => 3; }; -0`.

Comment: @JosephMarikle If you add multiple properties, however, it can't be a block statement anymore: `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` can't be a block statement because label statements can't occur after a comma (because they can't be part of an expression).

Comment: @Frxstrem That is so interesting.  Thanks for the explanation.  Interestingly, after forcing the object with a second property/method, it just throws a syntax error (at least in Chrome). `{valueOf:()=>3,a:0} - 0`.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Yes, I noticed.  I can't exactly explain why (I don't know the details of how JS is parsed), but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26347326) seems to have some interesting related answers if you're interested in this.

Answer (score 4):

`{} - 0`: here `{}` is just an empty block that does nothing, so `-0` returned by the console.

`({} - 0)`: here `{}` is a part of expression and is converted to a number. There is no `valueOf()` method defined in that empty object and, while converting to a number, it falls back to `toString()` method which returns something like `object Object` for `{}`. Then this string `object Object` is being converted into a number and gives `NaN` since it is actually not a number. So, we've got

`({} - 1)` -> `('object Object' - 1)` -> `(NaN - 1)`

and everything with `NaN` gives `NaN`. That's what you finally see in the console.

Answer (score 2):

```
{} - 0
```

is interpreted: `{} empty block statement` and `- 0 negative zero`

```
({} - 0)
```

all inside `()` is interpreted as an expression, `empty object - 0 = NaN`