# Why typing {}==[] in the Chrome console will report an error, and {}=={} will not report an error?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
{} == []
```

outputs:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==

wheres,

```
{} == {}
```

outputs

> false

Comment: Well, `[] == {}` works.

Comment: try `new Object({}) == new Array([]);`

Comment: Most likely `{}` is interpreted as a code block, but why type meaningless expressions in the console anyway ..?

Comment: Looks to be a console thing. `{} == {}` throws as a standalone line in normal JS

Comment: So why is the following {} not parsed into a statement block?

Comment: `{}` can either be parsed as a code block or as an object. It depends if it is the left-hand or right-hand side of the operation.

Comment: For JavaScript equality, [Zeroes in JS](http://zero.milosz.ca/) is extremely extensive.

Comment: In `NodeJS` both variants throw error :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Teemu is right. ({}) == [] works fine.

Comment: My main point to ask is, according to your explanation, why is {} == {} not reporting an error?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is an example of "sticking to your first thought"!

**Last edit:**
If you use `{` in the beginning of a line or after a closed statement, the JavaScript emulator will see this curly-bracked as the beginning of a code block. Therefore will the emulator see `}` as the closing of that block. this means that `== []` is standing alone in the middle of your code...

Wrapping it into round brackets, the emulator will translate it to an if-statement and then the `{` will be treated as the opening of an in-the-fly-object.

eg:

```
({} == []) // => false
```

<strike>**Edit:**</strike>

After some quick research, it seems that it is a rare case where the emulator fails.

Using Chrome 71:

If you type in the console `var a = {}` the output is `{}`. So a variable a is created, an empty object is created an stored into a.

But if you type `var b = []` the output is `undefined`. Here the emulator is messing up, because if you type `b`, the output is `[]`.
It means that the variable b is created, an object of type array is created and stored into b. But the return object of the array creation using the array literal is undefined.

Further testing shows me that `{} == function()` will throw the same error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ==`.
This make me **think** that using the array literal (`[]`) will returns a function that creates the array.

```
var b = [] // => literal returns a function that will be executed immediately
{} == b // => false because b holds the result of the executed literal-function.


{} == function() // throws error
{} == [] // throws error
var f = function() { --some code-- }
{} == f // throws error
```

Comment: Why is {} == {} not reporting errors?

Comment: "*using the array literal ([]) will returns a function that creates the array*" - uh, nooo.

Comment: Btw, `var a = {}` produces `undefined` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `{}` isn't interpreted as an empty object, but as an empty block.

The curly brackets use, in javascript, is ambiguous. It can be used both to define objects and to define blocks.

For example, the following block won't give you any error, because it's just a legal code block:

```
{
  console.log('hello world!');
}
```

So when you type `{} == []` you are comparing an empty block with an empty array, and it makes no sense.

When you type `{} == {}`, instead, the parser understands that you are comparing two objects and it returns false.

I guess this happens only because of the implementation and not because of specifications

Comment: How do you distinguish whether it is a block or an object? However, both expressions will be reported in the Firefox browser.

Comment: You can find an answer in the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347326/when-does-js-interpret-as-an-empty-block-instead-of-an-empty-object