# [] + {} is equal to [object Object], in Javascript? How?

Tags: javascript, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the)

I'm very new to JavaScript. I have a code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log( []  + {} );
</script>
```

which on my Google chrome browser logs :

```
[object Object]
```

It looks wired to me! And doing something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log( {} + {} );
</script>
```

does produce :

```
[object Object][object Object]
```

What is exactly happening over here in both the cases? How come `[]`,`{}` adding these two results in a array of `objects`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.shopify.com/technology/5370262-wat-a-funny-look-at-ruby-and-javascript-oddities

Comment: This question has been asked so many times !!!

Comment: Blast, didn't realize this was a duplicate when answering. Ah, well...

Comment: Sorry for that, I tried searching `[] + {}` but didn't get any relevant answers for it!

Comment: @Ant's: Yeah, hard thing to search for...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use the [`+` operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.6.1) with non-numbers, you're doing string concatenation, and so the operands are converted to strings. An empty array [becomes an empty string](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.2) because it's an implicit call to `join`, and with no entries, `join` returns an empty string; an object [becomes `"[object Object]"`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.2.4.2).

So

```
console.log( [] + {} );
```

...comes down to

```
console.log( String([]) + String({}) );
```

...which comes down to

```
console.log( "" + "[object Object]");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding object to array -  so it is put on the end.  When you apply + with  2 objects, only operation making sense is to convert to strings and concatenate it

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is an empty array, which is converted to a string (because of the concatenation operator). `{}` is an empty Object.