# Why does {} + [] return 0 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the)

I know that when `[]` is coerced to a string it returns the empty string (`""`), and when `{}` is coerced to a string it returns `"[object Object]"`.

When I run `[] + {}` in my browser's Javascript console, it returns as I would expect:

```
>> [] + {}
"[object Object]"
```

But when I run `{} + []`, it returns a completely unexpected value:

```
>> {} + []
0
```

What could be causing it to return `0`?

Comment: Looks like you are adding null to null.  This would be equivalent to 0 + 0.  That is just a guess though.

Comment: @Trisped: Neither of those are null.

Comment: This question is subsumed by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the (which as of now has 301 votes).....

Comment: has someone been watching "Wat" by destroyallsoftware? :P

Answer (score 68, accepted):

When there is a `{` at the beginning of a statement, it will be interpreted as a block, which may contain zero or more statements. An block with no statements in it will have an empty continuation value.

In other words, in this case, `{}` is interpreted as an empty code block.

The statement ends after the ending brace `}`, which means that the next three characters `+[]` comprise a statement of their own.

At the beginning of an expression or statement, `+` is the unary plus operator, which coerces its operand to a number.

So `+[]` is the same as `Number([])`, which evaluates to `0`.

In short, **`{} + []` is an empty code block followed by an array coerced to a number.**

---

All that said, if you evaluate `{} + []` *inside an expression*, it will return what you expect:

```
>> ({} + []) 
"[object Object]"
```

Another interesting thing is that you cannot begin a statement with an object literal because the interpreter will try to parse it as a statement. Doing this

```
{ "object": "literal" };
```

will throw a syntax error.

Comment: Interestingly, an object literal with a single property is not a syntax error at the beginning of a statement if you leave off the quotes on the property name. It just doesn't mean what it looks like it does. For example, `{ object: "literal" }` is interpreted as a block statement with a single statement, `"literal"`. `object` becomes a label for the statement.

Comment: @MatthewCrumley That is because `object:` is treated as a label (the ones you can use with break statements)

Comment: @Peter Olson. I appreciate your response. However, the expression `{ "object": "literal" };` will only throw an error in firefox. Chrome treats it as an object literal.

Answer (score 20):

Because the `{}` is treated as a block. Thus your statement is actually:

```
{

//empty block here
}

+[] //0 same as Number([])
```

This is why this is invalid javascript:

```
eval('{hello: "world", key: "value"}') //Syntax error
```

You can add () to make it an expression (blocks cannot be used in an expression so it will be object initializer:

```
eval('({hello: "world", key: "value"})') //Object
```

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me what is wrong with this answer, so please explain the downvote.

Comment: +1 to offset downvote..  You were about 25 seconds earlier, and I think your multi-line example is much clearer

Answer (score 2):

The empty block gets coerced into a zero. Then the `+` operator decides to coerce the `[]` to a number.

Comment: The empty block is an empty block, it's not coerced to anything.

Comment: @alex, you are correct, after reading Peter Olsen's answer, I understand that the only coercion is of the Array into a number and the first set of brackets is just ignored, the last statement is returned