# {} + [] in Javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the)

When I type

```
{} + []
```

in the Google Chrome JavaScript console, I get

```
0
```

as a result. However, when I type

```
Function("return {} + []")()
```

I get

```
"[object Object]"
```

as a result. I would think that both operations should return the same result, as one is simply a wrapper around the other. Why do they return different results?

Comment: The statement inside your function is different from the first statement.

Comment: `[object Object]` is just effect of using `({}).toString()` - do you `alert` your function result or do `console.log`?

Comment: `({}+[])` returns "[object Object]". As Mike explained below, it's the difference between a statement and an expression.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939044/why-does-return-0-in-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The core reason is that `{}` means a different thing in a statement context `{ statement0; statement1 }` than in an expression context `({ "property": value, ... })`.

```
 {} + []
```

is a block and a unary comparison operator so the same as

```
{}  // An empty block of statements.
(+ [])  // Use of prefix operator +.
```

The other is a use of the plus operator which when used with two objects concatenates them as in

```
return String({}) + String([])
```

Since `Array.prototype.toString` joins the array on commas, it is similar to

```
return String({}) + [].join(",")
```

which reduces to

```
return "[Object object]" + "";
```

and finally to

```
return "[Object object]"
```

Comment: Why is {} parsed differently in the two mentioned cases?

Comment: @MarkusRoth It's because function returns are evaluated as expressions; in which case an empty `{}` is evaluated as an object. The other case the `{}` was treated as an empty code block.