# Why does "{} == {}" result in a SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why {} != ( {} ) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115902/why-in-javascript)

I tried it today and it threw me **SyntaxError** today and it made me wonder; what's wrong with this?

```
{} === {}
{} == {}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When `{` is the first token in a line, it's considered the start of block.

```
{
  some();
  statements();
  here();
}
```

And not an object literal. A block of code cannot be equal to anything, it's not an assignable thing.

```
({}) === {}
```

That will set the parser straight.

Comment: Nit: "When `{` is the first token on a line.." is a gross approximation. Consider either `;(\n{} == {})` or `var x = \n{};` as counter-examples.

Answer (score 4):

Use parens.  Parentheses turn the ambiguous code into an expression:

```
({}) === ({})
```

Or:

```
({} === {})
```