# "{} === null" throws syntax error in developer console

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Why is it that when i type `{} === null` into the console it throws

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ===

`null === {}` gives me false as expected.

Comment: But it works in the node console.

Comment: Something to do with parsing the object literal. FYI, this works `({}) === null`

Comment: _"this only happens in the developer console"_ - No, you'll get an error if you include that in a script block in your webpage too.

Comment: @nnnnnn you're right, deleted that.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532355/why-does-result-in-a-syntaxerror

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `{}` is treated as an empty block. You can wrap it in parentheses to force an expression:

```
({} === null)
```