# Why is 0 === {} okay, but {} === 0 throws an error?

Tags: javascript

I put the following into the browser console:

```
0 === {} // false
{} === 0 // SyntaxError: expected expression, got '==='
```

Why is this?

Comment: the operator of the first object is called and the second is passed to it, could be there a reason?

Comment: Exact duplicate: [Why {} == 1 entered in console throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41302043/1048572), [“{} === null” throws syntax error in developer console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20753091/1048572)

Answer (score 12):

`{} === 0` here `{}` is block statement not object literal.

But if you do say `var a = {} === 0` it would work

```js
var a = {} === 0

console.log(a);
```

Comment: `{} === {}` is `false`. Why so?

Comment: or even just `console.log( {} === 0 );`

Comment: @31piy `{}` creates a new object, so `{} === {}` creates two objects. Two distinct objects are not equal even if they have the same keys and values. `var a = {}; console.log( a === a );` is `true`, since only one object was created and you are comparing it to itself.

Comment: @Paulpro I think 31piy is referring to the fact that {}==={} is not a syntax error

Comment: @Paulpro I think he wanted to state other thing about the fact of block statement.

Comment: @gman it doesn't work with equivalence either. `{} == {}` is also false;

Comment: @alaboudi I think you're right about 31piy's question. I'll just leave what I wrote there though, in-case anyone else is wondering why the comparison is `false` and not `true`.

Comment: @31piy https://stackoverflow.com/q/14115902/1048572

Comment: @31piy Hmmm, `{} === {} // false` only in Chrome, but fails as expected in other browsers and parsers. I have checked acorn, esprima, babylon, typescript.

Comment: @31piy Actually typescript parses it. But it parses `{} === 1` as well