# js casting and type coercion - Why !!{}[true] is not true?

Tags: javascript, casting, console

Typing in Chrome console:

```
{}[true]  // [true] (object)
!!{}[true] // false (boolean)
```

Why is !!{}[true] not true when {}[true] is?

Comment: Is this the full code or is part of a conditional statement? `{}[true]` by itself does not result in `true`.

Comment: [true for me](http://jsfiddle.net/xQpU7/).

Comment: @ShadowWizard: The parens are key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming these statements stand on their own:

`{}[true]` is interpreted as

```
{} // empty block
[true] // array literal expression
```

So if you type this in the console, the result of the last statement is printed, which is an array containing one element, the boolean value `true`.

`!!{}[true]` on the other hand is interpreted as accessing the property `'true'` of an empty object. This will return `undefined` and is converted to `false` when cast to a boolean.

Answer (score 8):

How did you evaluate `{}[true]`? Actually it's `undefined` since empty object doesn't have property named `'true'`. And it's obvious that `undefined` is not `true`.

**UPD**: I've checked it in Google Chrome Developer Tools and...

```
{}[true] // [true]
!!{}[true] // false
console.log({}[true]) // undefined
```

The first line is `[true]` since there are 2 statements involved. The first one is an empty block (`{}`) and the second one is an array with one element (true). In contrast second line evaluates as expression (as well as the argument in the third one), to `{}` which here is no longer a block but an empty object.

Comment: @san.chez, if we assume `{}` to be an object, then yes, it is. If we assume it as just javascript code, then it doesn't have any value since there are two statements (javascript doesn't have any last-statement-value-is-result-of-statement-list feature yet).

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the context. When JavaScript parser sees `{}` at the begining it thinks its a block of code, not object, thus effectively `{}[true]` is the same as `[true]` and indeed, in console:

```
> {}[true]
[true]
```

but

```
> x = {}[true];
undefined
```

because `{}` is not at the begining or

```
> ({}[true])
undefined
```

because `()` forces JS to treat it like an expression.

If JavaScript parser sees something in front of `{}` it interprets `{}` as object, thus in console:

```
> !!{}[true]
true
```

Comment: *"If JavaScript parser sees something in front of {}"*: Not for `{}{}[true]` ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, you're right, it's a bit simplified. :) But general idea is more or less correct.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> {}[true]  =>   true  (object)
> ```

Not really a boolean object. If at all, it returns an array with one item - the boolean true. This happens when `{}` is interpreted as an (empty) block (see [Why {} != ( {} ) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14115902/1048572)), and the second statement `[true]` is an array literal. If you tried

```
({}[true])
// or
({})[true]
```

(or force it in some other way to be evaluated as an expression) you access the `"true"` property of an empty object which is `undefined`. This happens in your second case as well:

> ```
> !!{}[true]  =>   false  (boolean)
> ```

as the `!!` coerces the `{}` to be interpreted as an object literal. And `!undefined` is `true`, so `!!undefined` will yield `false`.