# Why does CoffeeScript's string interpolation prefix the expression with an empty string?

Tags: javascript, string, coffeescript, string-interpolation

In CoffeeScript, the following statement evaluates to a JavaScript statement that is prefixed by an empty string.

I feel like there is an edge case with regards to type safety, but I can't think of it off the top of my head. In what case does the prefix make a difference?

CoffeeScript:

```
x = "#{foo} bar"
```

JavaScript:

```
x = "" + foo + " bar";
```

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but it's worth noting this bit of code I tried: `{a:'y'}+" thing"` => NaN but 
`""+{a:'y'}+" thing"` =>
"[object Object] thing". So my guess is that concatenating an object to an empty string calls `toString` on the object before concatenation

Comment: It regards steps 7 and 8 of [the `+` operator's definition](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) and ensures concatenation (7) vs. addition (8). A contrived example is `"#{3}#{4}"`. With the empty string at the start of the expression (`"" + 3 + 4`), it results in `"34"`. Without it (`3 + 4`), the result is `7`.

Comment: @Brennan: No. You fell prey to `{a:'y';}` being block syntax (see [these](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14115902/1048572) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17268468/1048572)). Try `({a:'y'})+" thing"`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, perfect explanation, thanks. Also, Bergi, thanks, great to know

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLonowski for the link to the operator definition! I finally understood whats going on here! The catch here is that with `{} + " bar"` what actually happens is that it goes into the 8th option (converting to number) which in turn tries to coerce the ToPrimitive of the object as a number, which in turn is NaN!

Comment: @KaushikShankar Using `{}` adds some additional complexity since they have 2 uses in JavaScript. When written on its own, `{} + " bar"` is actually two statements, `{};` and `+" bar";`, with a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) and [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)). The parenthesis Bergi mentioned make it an *Expression* and the `{}` an `Object` literal. `({}) + " bar"` results in `"[object Object] bar"`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks for the clarification! I see now why the `NaN` is the output; the `{}` returns `undefined` because its actually an invocation of a block, returning `undefined`, which is then converted to a number, and since `+ "bar"` is converted to `NaN` separately as a number as well, its sum is also `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ensures that the expression is always evaluated as a string, preventing e.g. numerical addition instead of concatenation.  In the case where a string only contains a single interpolated expression, it also effectively converts that expression to a string.  A couple of examples:

```
x = 2
y = 3

typeof "#{x}" is string   # true since this compiles to "" + x

str2 = "#{x}#{y}" # We want the string "23" here, not the number 5
```