# game server on node.js or netty

Tags: java, performance, node.js

I can't make a choice between node.js and Java(Netty). I wish to make a step based strategy with the game process like http://www.magicthegatheringtactics.com/ (users cooperates in the chatrooms and create a game sessions for 2-6 gamers. The gamers in the game session make his possible moves one by one)
I wish to use DB like postgreSQL or, maybe, new mysql version.
I'm expect around 4000 users maximum in one time. 
We will make a client side with Unity3d.

Can anybody help me to make a choise please?

Comment: i have no experience with node.js, but netty should definatly be a viable option

Comment: Did you find any database drivers for node? I only know the mysql connector.

Comment: [postgresql](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) driver is more mature and have a pure js/native bindings. 
I also recommend you the [any-db](https://github.com/grncdr/node-any-db), not for the abstraction layer but for the connection pool which is really useful :)

Comment: Btw, let me know which one you choose, I have a "similar" project that requires binding unity and nodejs via tcp or udp.

Answer (score 3):

There are many people talking about speed, throughput and performance.
You can often hear "node.js is faster, because its asyc".

1. You can write async Java, too
2. Async is not faster than Threading, It scales better, if you start to many threads
3. The "job" needs the same time if it is signaling its state with events or inside a thread.

Some links:
http://amix.dk/blog/post/19577#Is-node-js-best-for-Comet
http://www.olympum.com/java/java-aio-vs-nodejs/

From my point of view:

node.js is some kind of hype. If you are good in JavaScript use node, if you are good in Java, use Java. There are many thinks I don't like in JavaScript
[What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the)

or even funnier: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXEgk1Hdze0

Answer (score 1):

Java will be way faster in computing and Node faster in IO.
If you're thinking of Java and Node, I think computing isn't your biggest problem so make your choice on which language YOU will be faster to make your server.

Comment: Do you have any benchmark about the IO-thing? There are many people talking about the advantages of node, but I have only seen benchmarks where java was the winner (Like this one: http://blog.creapptives.com/post/9677133069/node-on-nails )

Comment: I saw 2 but i bookmarked only one and i'm to lazy to find the other :p
http://blog.evanweaver.com/2012/02/29/hello-heroku-world/

Comment: Finally, i searched a bit and I found an other one, not the one i expected but anyway :
http://weblog.plexobject.com/?p=1698 (be careful to read the X&Y axis values cause the scales differ)

Comment: That are the results I was expecting. The Java Virtual Maschine had years to become faster and faster. node.js is quite new and the V8 is great but had another focus than to become a backend server. The time and bandwith of the server will not change, if one switch from java to node. A JVM is really fast after the warmup-phase. But thanks for googling another benchmark ;)