# Why 0 == '' is true in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, equals

Why, in Javascript,

```
0 == ''
```

is true ?

http://jsfiddle.net/TXhCs/

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the)

Comment: I hate fiddles with alerts...

Comment: U are right. Sorry. It's a bad habit, I will try to avoid it ..

Comment: 0 is false, `''` is false; they are both false (0), that's why.

Comment: Not exactly. You can find the specific answer in the other question ... excatly here http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

That is because javascript is attempting to do a type conversion on `''` since `''` is a type `String` and `0` is a `number` type. `''`, when converted to a number, is `0`

Comment: there is no conversion to a `Boolean` here.  The _result_ of the `==` operation is a boolean, though.

Comment: Yeah sorry I realized that was incorrect after I wrote it. Thanks for the tip, I edited my response - doesn't matter since the question is closed now anyways.