# What would be the explanation for the strange javascript expression?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript the following line of code gives answer as 1

```
+ ! {} [true]
```

I couldn't understand how?

Any gurus explanation is appreciated.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXEgk1Hdze0

Comment: `+!{}[0]` gives **1** try to understand the meaning...

Comment: @elclanrs Oh I love that video.

Comment: @elclanrs hilarious. thanks for sharing.

Comment: related: [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the)

Comment: Without minutes this puzzle was solved. I love you 'SO' community. thanks a lot.

Comment: sorry for the typo *within minutes

Comment: Related: [Why does !{}\[true\] evaluate to true in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19702805)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{}` is an empty object.

So `{}[0]` or `{}[true]` or `{}[1]` etc.. are `undefined`

adding `!` casts `{}[0]` as a `boolean`, returning the opposite. (`undefined` becoming `false`, it therefore returns `true`).

adding `+` casts it as an `int`, so `true` becomes `1`.

Comment: did the question change from [0] to [true]?

Comment: No, `{}` is not undefined. It's an empty object.

Comment: @RomainBraun: actually, this is trickier than it seems. I've posted an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16480480/989121

Comment: plus one for the + casting tip. Needed it just after I read this.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to explain it through code .

```
var emptyObject = {};
    valueOfUndefinedKey = emptyObject['key_not_exists'],
    itsNot = !valueOfUndefinedKey ,
    finalConvertedNumber = +itsNot ;

console.log(
    emptyObject,
    valueOfUndefinedKey,
    itsNot,
    finalConvertedNumber
)
```

which prints

```
Object {}

undefined

true

1
```