# Inconsistency in JS console when adding arrays and objects

Tags: javascript

I don't want to ask why [] + [] gives you empty string, or so on, as we can't change it. And the reason is just a design of the language.

My question is about following inconsistency, noticed in Chrome and FF Firebug JS consoles:

```
{} + []; // outputs 0
console.log({} + []); // outputs [object Object]
var c = {} + [];
console.log(c); // outputs [object Object]
```

I understand that expression returns a value, and this is what you see in console output. But why this return value changes, when assigned to a variable or output using `console.log()`?

Does it mean that mentioned consoles are buggy?

Is there any better explanation then stating that *this is the way it's done*?

Comment: Why not remove the cases where every place gives the *same* output? It’s just clutter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the)

Comment: @Bergi you're right - they touch this very same issue. Thanks for posting this link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, it is just a block, so it is equivalent to running this code (the plus in front of the array literal converts it to a number):

```
{};
+[]; // 0
```

However, in your console.log code, it is considered an expression, so it is in fact an object literal.  You can only pass expressions to functions, so this is the same.

```
function a(b) {return b;}
a({}+[]); // "[object Object]"
```

The addition operation converts them to a string, so that's why you get `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: Instead of that `identity` function a simple grouping operator would've been enough: `({}+[])` ;-)

Comment: @Bergi: it was to prove the point that when passing arguments to a function, they are passed as expressions - just like the `console.log()` example.

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with `console.log()`.

In `{} + []` the `{}` is parsed as a block, whereas in the second two cases, it is parsed as an object as a part of an expression.

This is made evident by the fact that, `console.log()` or not, `var a = {} + []` sets `a` to an object.

You can simplify the second two cases even further by simply adding parenthesis (which makes it an expression):

```
({} + [])  //=> "[object Object]"
```

Comment: This code convinced me the most: `({} + [])`. It's indeed a block. Thanks!