# Why {} + {} is NaN only on the client side? Why not in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval, google-chrome-devtools, web-developer-toolbar

While `[] + []` is an empty string, `[] + {}` is `"[object Object]"`, and `{} + []` is `0`. Why is `{} + {}` NaN?

```
> {} + {}
  NaN
```

My question isn't why `({} + {}).toString()` is `"[object Object][object Object]"` while `NaN.toString()` is `"NaN"`, [this part has an answer here already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9033306/1348195).

My question is why does this happen only on the client side? On the server side ([Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)) `{} + {}` is `"[object Object][object Object]"`.

```
> {} + {}
'[object Object][object Object]'
```

---

**Summarizing**:

On the client side:

```
 [] + []              // Returns ""
 [] + {}              // Returns "[object Object]"
 {} + []              // Returns 0
 {} + {}              // Returns NaN

 NaN.toString()       // Returns "NaN"
 ({} + {}).toString() // Returns "[object Object][object Object]"
 var a = {} + {};     // 'a' will be "[object Object][object Object]"
```

In Node.js:

```
 [] + []   // Returns "" (like on the client)
 [] + {}   // Returns "[object Object]" (like on the client)
 {} + []   // Returns "[object Object]" (not like on the client)
 {} + {}   // Returns "[object Object][object Object]" (not like on the client)
```

Comment: see also the spec: http://es5.github.io/

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks! They don't talk about NodeJS.

Comment: It's just the browser console that does that. Try logging **to** the console and it's the same as in NodeJS. http://jsbin.com/oveyuj/1/edit

Comment: Not really a duplicate, I am asking for NodeJS answer. Voting for reopen...

Comment: Hmm... sorry. However, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the is still relevant and answers the first half

Comment: Don't forget that `{}` can be interpreted either as an expression or as an object primitive depending on context. Maybe the code is the same on client and on server but it is interpreting `{}` differently due to different context of entering the code.

Comment: @elclanrs Not only in the browser. I've installed `rhino` in terminal that does the same thing (`{} + {}` is `NaN`).

Comment: Like @Patashu said, it must be the context. Not sure what the subtle differences are in all these environments...

Comment: Concerning the node.js console, I'm guessing it's due to how the console is implemented. If the node.js console does `eval("x="+input)`, it will behave as observed

Comment: @JanDvorak This should be an answer, the node console uses [this](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html).

Comment: @JanDvorak Also, it's more likely that it's because `new Function('return {}+{}')()` returns `"[object Object][object Object]"`. (At least according to the docs)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum are you willing to dig in the sources and then post an answer?

Comment: Please reopen and then **stop closing this question again and again** since this question is really *not a duplicate*.

Comment: http://www.benjiegillam.com/2013/06/quantum-javascript/ answers this in more detail.

Comment: @MathiasBynens Actually it's _less_ detail because it doesn't explain _why_ it evaluates this way in nodejs ("And I’m guessing that Node’s REPL,") :) Thanks for the link though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Note that this isn’t a comment to your answer, which is excellent!

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Updated note: [this has been fixed in Chrome 49](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=499864).

Very interesting question! Let's dig in.

### The root cause

The root of the difference is in how Node.js evaluates these statements vs. how the Chrome development tools do.

### What Node.js does

Node.js uses the [repl](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) module for this.

From the Node.js [REPL source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/repl.js#L253):

```
self.eval(
    '(' + evalCmd + ')',
    self.context,
    'repl',
    function (e, ret) {
        if (e && !isSyntaxError(e))
            return finish(e);
        if (typeof ret === 'function' && /^[\r\n\s]*function/.test(evalCmd) || e) {
            // Now as statement without parens.
            self.eval(evalCmd, self.context, 'repl', finish);
        }
        else {
            finish(null, ret);
        }
    }
);
```

This acts just like running `({}+{})` in the Chrome developer tools, which also produces `"[object Object][object Object]"` as you'd expect.

### What the chrome developer tools do

On the other hand [Chrome dveloper tools does the following](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git/+/master/Source/core/inspector/InjectedScriptSource.js):

```
try {
    if (injectCommandLineAPI && inspectedWindow.console) {
        inspectedWindow.console._commandLineAPI = new CommandLineAPI(this._commandLineAPIImpl, isEvalOnCallFrame ? object : null);
        expression = "with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {\n" + expression + "\n}";
    }
    var result = evalFunction.call(object, expression);
    if (objectGroup === "console")
        this._lastResult = result;
    return result;
}
finally {
    if (injectCommandLineAPI && inspectedWindow.console)
        delete inspectedWindow.console._commandLineAPI;
}
```

So basically, it performs a `call` on the object with the expression. The expression being:

```
with ((window && window.console && window.console._commandLineAPI) || {}) {
    {}+{};// <-- This is your code
}
```

So, as you can see, the expression is being evaluted directly, without the wrapping parenthesis.

### Why Node.js acts differently

Node.js's source justifies this:

```
// This catches '{a : 1}' properly.
```

Node did not always act like this. Here is [the actual commit that changed it](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/b45698e67629a894cc005efba5c39d0e8adae1b0#lib/repl.js). Ryan left the following comment on the change: "Improve how REPL commands are evaled" with an example of the difference.

---

#### Rhino

Update - OP was interested in how **Rhino** behaves (and why it behaves like the Chrome devtools and unlike nodejs).

Rhino uses a completely different JS engine unlike the Chrome developer tools and Node.js's REPL which both use V8.

Here is the basic pipe line of what happens when you eval a JavaScript command with Rhino in the Rhino shell.

- The shell runs [`org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.main`](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/toolsrc/org/mozilla/javascript/tools/shell/Main.java).
- In turn, it calls [this](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/toolsrc/org/mozilla/javascript/tools/shell/Main.java#L340) `new IProxy(IProxy.EVAL_INLINE_SCRIPT);` for example, if the code was passed directly with the inline switch -e.
- This hits IProxy's [`run`](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/toolsrc/org/mozilla/javascript/tools/shell/Main.java#L102) method.
- It invokes [`evalInlineScript`](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/toolsrc/org/mozilla/javascript/tools/shell/Main.java#L196-L202) ([src](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5801684/)). This simply compiles the string and evals it.

Basically:

```
Script script = cx.compileString(scriptText, "<command>", 1, null);
if (script != null) {
    script.exec(cx, getShellScope()); // <- just an eval
}
```

Out of the three, Rhino's shell is the one that does the closest thing to an actual `eval` without any wrapping. Rhino's is the closest to an actual `eval()` statement and you can expect it to behave exactly like `eval` would.

Comment: (Not really a part of the answer, but worth mentioning nodejs uses the [vm module](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/vm.html) for evaling by default when using the REPL, and not just a JavaScript `eval`)

Comment: Can you explain why **rhino**, for example, does the same thing in Terminal (not only Chrome Console)?

Comment: +10 if it was possible! Wow man,... You really don't have life or you are really smarter than me to know something like that.  Please,  tell me that you searched a little bit to found this answer :)

Comment: @Samuel All it took is reading the source - I swear! In Chrome, if you enter 'debugger;' , you get the whole pipe - it will throw you _directly_ to the 'with' with just one function above to `evaluateOn`. In node, everything is very well documented - they have a dedicated REPL module with all the history nice and cozy on git, having used REPLs before on my own programs, I knew where to look :) I'm glad you liked it and found it helpful, but I owe it to my familiarity with these code bases (dev-tools and nodejs) rather than my intellect. Going straight to the source is often always the easiest.

Comment: Update - the console API in Chrome has been updated a bit so while the general idea here is correct, the code posted is not accurate for the most recent version of Chrome. See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink.git/+/master/Source/core/inspector/InjectedScriptSource.js#688

Comment: Why does the with statement executed deep within the chrome developer tools force {} to be evaluated in a numeric context?  If it was +{}+{}  that'd convince me, except +{}+{} is 'Nan[object Object]' in both chrome developer tools and nodeJS

Comment: @Paul It gets executed as "Open a new code block, close it, then calculate `+{}`, Doing `+x` in JavaScript is exactly the same as doing `Number(x)` in JavaScript. So it gets executed as `Number({})` which is NaN

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I was the one who downvoted you because it didn't look good, but I upvoted it now because you updated your answer to be more detailed.

Comment: @İnekŞaban you didn't even have an account at the point of the last edit. what the hell are you on about?

Comment: @rlemon I don't know if you read my post on Meta, but I have the habit to switch to a new account and ip address regularly. But I just wanted to come back to see if it was better, hence the upvote.

Comment: I presume your old account was deleted, so the negative vote would have been removed.

Comment: @rlemon I'm here since late 2009 and it sometimes happen that an account get stuck in a ban (I presume because I share this connection with many people [it's a public hotspot]) and I make a new account thereof. But I mostly just switch for personal reasons.

Comment: @İnekŞaban link to your old account?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum What do you want to do with it? It's here anyway http://stackoverflow.com/users/107560/caglar-toklu If you delete it you won't resolve nothing, so please keep on a constructive standpoint. I don't want troubles and you don't want too.