# Why does Node REPL not give the same results as Wat video or my browser console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For example, in both [Wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat) and in my Chrome browser:

```
{} + {}
```

is `NaN`

But in Node REPL, it's

```
[object Object][object Object]
```

The latter admittedly makes more sense to me - coercing to string and then acting is a pretty reasonable thing to do.  However I don't understand where this discrepancy comes from, and therefore, don't understand how much I can trust the REPL to understand some simple JS behavior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why {} + {} is NaN only on the client side? Why not in Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268468/why-is-nan-only-on-the-client-side-why-not-in-node-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{}` is both an expression (an empty object literal) and a statement (an empty block).

`eval()` will try to parse its input as a statement.
If it isn't a "normal" statement (eg, an `if`), it will be parsed as an expression statement, which evaluates an expression.

Therefore, `{} + {}` is parsed as two statements (via ASI): `{}; +{}`.  The first statement is an empty block; the second statement is the *unary* `+` operator which coerces an object to a number.
Coercing an object to a number involves calling `toString()` (which returns `"[object Object]"`), then parsing the result as a number (which it isn't).
`eval()` then returns that as the value of the final statement.

Node [wraps its REPL input](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/repl.js#L251-L253) in `()` to force it to be parsed as an expression:

```
  // First we attempt to eval as expression with parens.
  // This catches '{a : 1}' properly.
  self.eval('(' + evalCmd + ')',
```

Comment: and with that, I think I actually understand all of the JS in the wat vidoe. Thanks.