# JavaScript assignment changes the addition operation semantics?

Tags: javascript

If you evaluate `{} + 1` you get `1`, but if you assign the same expression to a variable, say `x = {} + 1`, the variable will hold a string `"[object Object]1"`.

Why does the assignment change the semantics of the right-hand side expression? Shouldn't the right-hand side expression be "context-free"?

Comment: In what context are you able to get a result of just `1`?

Comment: You don't get `1` everywhere. In `node.js` you don't get it. In Chrome and Firefox yes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/jgMGs/ `{} + 1 !== 1`

Comment: Browser's JavaScript console of an empty page. In my case the browser is Chrome.

Comment: @thriqon: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17455668/34397

Comment: thanks for the link... always nice to learn something new :)

Comment: I'm curious, what led you to the expression `{} + 1`?

Comment: I get "[object Object]1" in both cases on Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Peter: I'm building an F# to scripting languages (among which JavaScript) compiler, and I was doing some experiments ... :)

Comment: @user1671639, [you can't simply call it within an `alert` because it'll change the context to an assignment, you need to evaluate that code as an expression](http://jsfiddle.net/jgMGs/1/).

Comment: @zzzzBov didn't realized it, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{} + 1
```

is interpreted as a code block followed by `+1`, which evaluates to `1`. OTOH:

```
x = {} + 1
```

is evaluated as `new Object()` plus `1`

If you change your original statement to:

```
new Object() + 1
```

You will see `"[object Object]1"` as a result.