# Why {} == {} is false, but {} + {} == {} + {} is true

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why in node.js is `{} == {}` equivalent to `false`, but is `{} + {} == {} + {}` equivalent to `true`?

```
> {} == {}
false
```

```
> {} + {} == {} + {}
true
```

Comment: Related: [WAT?](http://destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)

Comment: In Chrome it's false, just out of interest.

Comment: @RichBradshaw didn't test with Chrome, only with node.

Comment: I think a good answer to this question should address why node behaves different than the console in web browsers like chrome/ff

Comment: Have you bothered logging the values you're comparing?

Comment: @chris: I've expanded my answer to address that.

Comment: @RichBradshaw Of course it is, [**Chrome's dev tools JS console and NodeJS do REPL differently**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268468/why-is-nan-only-on-the-client-side-why-not-in-node-js/17269376#17269376).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`+` here is the string-concatenation operator. This:

```
{} == {}
```

means "if I create one object with `{}`, and another object with `{}`, are they the same object?"; and the answer is "no".

This:

```
{} + {} == {} + {}
```

means "is the primitive string `"[object Object][object Object]"` the same as the primitive string `"[object Object][object Object]"`?"; and the answer is "yes".

---

**Edited to add:** A number of commenters point out that in the Web Console of a browser like Firefox or Chrome, your second expression also prints `false` . . . but for a different reason.

The reason for this, as [jJ'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470331/jj) has explained in a comment, is that the browser's Web Console does not specifically require an expression; it will happily accept something like `if(true) { }`. So, when it sees `{} + {} == {} + {}`, it doesn't interpret that as an expression; the initial `{}` is interpreted as a naked block, then the `+ {} == {} + {}` is interpreted as an expression, and the Web Console displays the result of that expression, which is `false`, because `+ {}` evaluates to NaN (the unary `+` triggers numeric conversion) and `{} + {}` evaluates to `"[object Object][object Object]"` (as before).

This behavior, by the way, is not completely specific to the Web Console. `eval` follows the same rules, so `eval('{} + {} == {} + {}')` is `false`.

This can be fixed, both in the Web Console and in `eval`, by using parentheses; `({} + {} == {} + {})`, for example, returns `true`, because it prevents the interpretation of `{}` as a naked block and therefore forces its interpretation as an object.

Comment: Yes, i saw "[object Object][object Object]" result from {} + {}, i'm new in node.js and did not pay attention that it is just a string, i thought that it's node's internal data type :), now i see that `typeof ({} + {})` is `string`. Thank you for great answer and explanation

Comment: @ruakh:  Great explanation! Any thoughts on why `{} + {} == {} + {}` returns `false` in chrome and firefox?

Comment: @go-oleg Because in FF `{} + {}` is `NaN`. And `NaN == NaN` is false, because **NaN is never equal to itself**. See this explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FNaN

Comment: @go-oleg: I've expanded my answer to address that. It turns out to be pretty complicated!

Comment: in chrome and FF console {} and ({}) are different things because of the ambiguity of block vs. object literal. "{} + {}" on the left hand side is like parse and ignore empty block "{}" and then try to convert object "{}" to a number using "+" because after the operator an expression is expected. on the right hand side it expects expression and so it concatenates two {}.toString(). So there is even more "trickery" there :). Node on the other hand uses a different way of evaluation, so it does not interpret an empty block.

Comment: @jJ': Oh, that makes so much sense! I'll update the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the world of JavaScript. :) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THERgYM8gBM

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268468/why-is-nan-only-on-the-client-side-why-not-in-node-js/17269376#17269376) on why it behaves this way in Node's REPL but not in Chrome.