# Constructor property of Java Script types

Tags: javascript

I'm leaning JavaScript and I've read about the `constructor` property.

I tried

1. `[].constructor`
2. `false.constructor`
3. `'abc'.constructor`

And they all worked. However to my surprise when trying:

1. `123.constructor`
2. `{}.constructor`

They did not, why is that?

Comment: Try `123..constructor`, the first '.' is a decimal mark. `{}.constructor` works for me.

Comment: @Korikulum where? That's a syntax error in the chrome dev tools. It [depends on where you're running it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268468/why-is-nan-only-on-the-client-side-why-not-in-node-js/17269376#17269376).

Comment: Suggest what? You haven't told us what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, you're right, I was doing the following: `console.dir({}.constructor);`, and that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a parse issue.

- When you do `123.constructor` the engine experts a decimal after the `123` like `123.123`
- When you do `{}.constructor` the engine reads `{}` as an empty block and then reads `.` as the first thing in the outer block which is meaningless.

Both of which can be fixed by wrapping these with `()`s

```
(123).constructor; // Number, note this 'boxes'
({}).constructor; // Object
```