# Why is typeof's result different than the evaluated result of the expression passed in?

Tags: javascript, object, types, nan, typeof

If two **Objects** added together equal **NaN**(not a number), which is technically of type **number**, then why does getting the type of two **Objects** added together result in **"string"**?

I will express this via the REPL:
`> {} + {}`
`> NaN`
ok. two objects added together creates NaN

`> typeof(NaN)`
`> "number"`
ok. we know that NaN's type is "number"

`> typeof({} + {})`
`> "string"`
wait.  shouldn't this have been "number" also?

I'm aware that javascript has a less then desireable type system, but I'm confused as to what's happening here.  Is the type being converted from number to string for some reason?  Is number even a part of the type converting that goes on here?  Or am I just using typeof wrong?

Comment: `{}+{} !== ({}+{})` [Unary_plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus)

Comment: The first braces form a block. Because JavaScript. See also this awesome talk featuring this very example: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{} + {}` is an empty **block** (`{}`) followed by a type conversion from object to number (`+{}`). It basically reads as

```
{} // empty block (a statement)
;  // empty statement (just for clarity)
+{}; // expression statement (unary plus, object literal -> conversion to number)
```

However if you use `typeof ({} + {})`, then `{} + {}` will be evaluated as **expression** in which case both `{}` can only be object literals and the `+` is the concatenation operator.

You can also just use the grouping operator to force the construct to be evaluated as expression:

```
({} + {}) // expression statement (string concatenation with two objects)
```

---

See also [Why {} + {} is NaN only on the client side? Why not in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17268468/218196) and other questions related to [`[javascript] "{} + {}"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%22%7B%7D+%2B+%7B%7D%22).