# Why plus operator in brackets works differently?

Tags: javascript

Could you please explain why the results are different?

1. `({} + {})` // = "[object Object][object Object]"
2. `{} + {}`   // = NaN

I understand that in both cases objects are converted to strings, but why in the second case the result is converted to a number?

Comment: It's not the plus operator that is acting different, it's those curly braces that are once an object literal and once something else

Comment: what is "something" ?)

Comment: Tip: trailing semicolons matter

Comment: @Ezee: Read the linked post. It's not an expression, but an empty block statement. more details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26347326/1048572)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Do you mean `{};  +{}`?

Comment: @Bergi: That dupe doesn't answer why `({} + {})` returns something else than `{} + {}` does.

Comment: Well, the answer is trailing semicolons indicated by @ÁlvaroG.Vicario

Comment: Care to elaborate in an actual answer?

Comment: question should be re-opened

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25416725/1048572

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From:

http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html

> The problem is that JavaScript interprets the first {} as an empty
> code block and ignores it. The NaN is therefore computed by evaluating
> +{} (plus followed by the second {}). The plus you see here is not the binary addition operator, but a unary prefix operator that converts
> its operand to a number, in the same manner as Number()
>
> ...
>
> Why is the first {} interpreted as a code block? Because the complete
> input is parsed as a statement and curly braces at the beginning of a
> statement are interpreted as starting a code block. Hence, you can fix
> things by forcing the input to be parsed as an expression:
>
> ({} + {})
>
> '[object Object][object Object]'