# Functional Programming in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Im not sure it this is allowed here, if it is not please tell me where I can ask this.

Although I have herd JavaScript is easy language to learn, i find it very difficult to learn. I am reading about functional programming(Ch 6) in [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html). The whole point seems to be that functional programming is a way to make your programs more clear and intent by using functions to encapsulate ugly little details like a for loop, I get that. What drives me insane is trying to follow code that has a function within a function that returns a function that takes function values as parameters, ect... ect.... My head just spins after a while and I dont see that it makes my life any easier although the final program does look nicer.. Is this just something you get use to? or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: *"The whole point seems to be that functional programming is a way to make your programs more clear and intent by using functions to encapsulate ugly little details like a for loop"* You also do this in procedural programming. Functional programming is "more" than that.

Comment: Like everything in life, it gets easier with practice. Stick at it. :-) Incidentally, pretty much every "approach" in programming is about abstraction/encapsulation so the lessons you're learning now will pay dividends when/if you take on other languages.

Comment: I'd say the purpose of functional programming is to avoid state; making them clearer is just a handy side effect.  It's a very different way of thinking, and one that will take time to figure out.  However, once you learn it, you'll be able to write some really beautiful code, and you'll be a better programmer.

Comment: Once you learn that, you will have no more issues with JavaScript, but it does take some time to get your head around. JavaScript scopes are all functional. The reason you're downvoted is because you need a more specific question.

Comment: @MattBryant: You cannot avoid state when you're *doing* something. Imho the point of FP is to use state explicitly, and in a way that you can abstract some things over it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main issue in using javascript to learn functional programming is that javascript doesn't enforce a functional style. While you can write pure functions in javascript, it is very easy not to. Furthermore, despite being easy to learn, javascript is a language with a lot of quirks; it's fairly hard to get a full understanding of the language's mechanics. Another issue is that Javascript doesn't provide most of the features that makes functional programming so fun: lambda expressions, pattern matching, etc aren't built into the language.

If your aim is to learn functional programming I would advice you to use a pure functional language such as Haskell. If, however, you want to learn Javascript specifically make sure you go in depth into understanding concepts such as the prototype chain, type coercion, automatic semicolon insertion, scoping, etc. Here are some useful resources:

- I personally enjoyed "Effective JavaScript: 68 Specific Ways to Harness the Power of JavaScript" by David Herman. Excellent book.
- Chrome console! Try out everything you read.
- Esprima online parser (http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html). Very useful to see how a piece of code is parsed.
- Eventually "The Good Parts" by Douglas Crockford but only for the easy introduction that it provides. I don't think the book is a reference in terms of "beautiful code". For that, read David Herman's book.
- The epic "WAT" by Gary Bernhardt (https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)
- Mozilla's documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- The ECMA specification (with moderation) (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)

Good luck!

Comment: I don't think you linked the right Youtube video

Comment: Oh, that one. I wouldn't really consider that a "*useful resource*" -[this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the) is one :-)

Comment: A bit of fun while learning a language isn't inappropriate :p And yes, looking behind the quirks to understand where they come from is essential!

Answer (score 0):

I sheep dipped myself into functional programming outside of my *normal* languages *first*. I didn't start doing it in Javascript, but learnt some Scheme, OCaml and f# first. I found brining the principles back to Javascript easier that way.

Javascript is great as a functional language (in my opinion). For example, a Javascript constructor is a monad (great video on this here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0EF0VTs9Dc).

I would say, Yes, you will have to get used to it - but the easiest way to do that is outside of JS. Recursion (for example) is a real head-bake when you are used to loops. (Tip: work out your exit condition first!).

Keep at it!

Comment: Could you please explain how a javascript constructor is a monad? (Or link to the specific moment of the talk where Doug shows it)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=b0EF0VTs9Dc&t=714 "a function that takes a value and returns an object"

Comment: Then you understood it wrong. He says that the `unit` function is a constructor. Only together with a `bind` function it will create a monadic type.

Comment: So, how would you describe a monad? (Forgiving, obviously, the case that as soon as you understand monads you lose the ability to explain them)

Comment: For example, if arrays were the monad (they indeed are one), then `Array` (or better literals, which work for one argument) are the type constructor and `bind` would be concatMap (`Array.prototype.bind = function(f){return [].concat.apply([], this.map(f));}`)

Comment: Thanks! I am going to have to digest that a little. Would it be correct that the result of a constructor is a monad - because a monad is an object?

Comment: I'm sorry, that comment was supposed to augment my second one, not to be an answer on your question. Indeed, I have already lost the ability to define them (I only do know [they're not](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/What_a_Monad_is_not) burritos). They're an abstract concept that is very helpful for composing things.