# What is the reasoning behind isNaN's implementation?

Tags: javascript, standards, ecmascript-6

Although the name of the function `isNaN` refers semantically to the value `isNaN`, the native implementation returns `true` for some non-`NaN` objects like `undefined` or `{}`.

```
isNaN(undefined);
=> true
```

I think, e.g., underscore's implementation is much more intuitive/logical:

```
_.isNaN(undefined);
=> false
```

Why did the ECMA standard specify such a counterintuitive behavior?

Why didn't they design `isNaN` to return `true` **only** if the value to test is 
*really* `isNaN` and leave the burden to test for convertability-to-number on a separate `isNumber` function?

Doing it this way would have led to even more advantages like no *double negative* when testing for numbers:

```
if (isNumber(x)) { } // if x is a number
```

instead of

```
if (!isNaN(x)) { }   // if x is not not a number
```

Since they are going to introduce `Number.isNaN()` in ECMAScript 6 (which does exactly what you would expect from it), it looks like there are more people thinking like this.

So, why did they design `isNaN` the way it is in the first place? Was it just a wrong decision or was there a good reasoning to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the)

Comment: The ECMA standard was finalized at a point in time when thousands (if not millions) of pages relied on code working with the language as it stood at the time.

Comment: _"I had to be done in ten days or something worse than JS would have happened."_ – Brendan Eich.

Comment: The referenced question is quite interesting, but how is this question a duplicate of it?

Comment: I don't see how this qualified as an answerable question. What do you want to know, exactly? What "their" motivation was? "Their" frame of mind? Ask *them*, not StackOverflow.....

Comment: Read the answer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482500/mdn-object-is-alternative-proposal. Too bad your question got closed +1 ;)

Comment: To answer your question read the page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN