# MDN "Object.is" alternative proposal

Tags: javascript, object, methods, ecmascript-6

I have read [the MDN page on the "Object.is" method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is).
It gives an alternative code for the browsers that do not provide this method:

```
if (!Object.is) {
    Object.is = function(v1, v2) {
        if (v1 === 0 && v2 === 0) {
            return 1 / v1 === 1 / v2;
        }
        if (v1 !== v1) {
            return v2 !== v2;
        }
        return v1 === v2;
    };
}
```

The question is simple: when can the second "if" be true ?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It kinda is written in [the same article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is#Description):

> This is also not the same as being equal according to the ===
>   operator.  The === operator (and the == operator as well) treats the
>   number values -0 and +0 as equal, and ***it treats Number.NaN as not
>   equal to NaN***.

The logic is that `NaN !== NaN` is the only case in which the `!==` operator returns `true` on the same variable, so it must be about `NaN` comparison. It then does the same check on `v2` and returns true of false based on the outcome: *if `v2` comparison is `true`, it's about NaN compared to NaN so return `true`, if not then return `false` because NaN is never the same as something that isn't NaN*.

Comment: Well, the article says that only Number.NaN!==NaN will return true but not NaN!==NaN ... here v1 is tested against v1... that means NaN against NaN or Number.NaN against Number.NaN. I still not understand...

Comment: `Number.NaN` or `NaN`, doesn't matter. JavaScript has only one `NaN` logically.

Comment: For clarity NaN===NaN will be false. NaN is just an alias for Number.NaN

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, that we have more than only 1 NaN:

```js
var notNaN = new DataView(new Uint8Array([0x7f, 0xf8,0,0,0,0,0,1]).buffer).getFloat64(0)
Object.is(notNaN, NaN) // true

const byteOf = (number, index) => {let v = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(8)); v.setFloat64(0, number); return v.getUint8(index);}

byteOf(NaN, 7) // 0
byteOf(notNaN, 7) // 1
```

So there are two distinguishable values, but Object.is() says, they are the same