# What converts to number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers, type-conversion

What's the secret behind (weird) number conversion in JavaScript?

I've manage to figure out some using `isnumeric` function on couple of test cases presented below.

```
//
function isnumeric(n) {
  try {
    return (isFinite(n = n.valueOf()) || ((1 / 0 === Math.abs(n)) && (n + n === n)))
      && eval(n) === parseFloat(Number(n));
  } catch (b) {}
  return false;
}

console.clear();
[
.1, 1, 0, "0", Infinity, 1/0, -1/0, +null, 01, 037, 1 + [], 
Math.pow([], 2), 0xff, 0x12ef, +[], -[], -1/[], []/Infinity, 
"0x12", 1/null, null/1, Math.sqrt([]), []/1, Infinity/[], new Date, 
Math.E, "1.2e-12", 0.1e11, null + +[], Math.sqrt(null), 1/"\t\r\n ",
" \t\r\n\uFEFF\xA0\x0B\u2028\u2029\u1680\u180E\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u202F\u205F\u3000"/1
].every(isnumeric);
//
// true
//
```

`isFinite(n = n.valueOf())` deals with *numeric-like-values*(strings, numbers, dates),

`(1 / 0 === Math.abs(n)) && (n + n === n)` filters out `Infinity` from (string) `"Infinity"`,

`eval(n) === parseFloat(Number(n))` part handles *string-numerics* holding characters: "x, e" etc.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: EEK. `eval`ing random strings is a bad idea.

Comment: >>> What's the secret behind (weird) number conversion in JavaScript? <<<

Comment: Can you elaborate on what that means? Which number conversions? In what context?

Comment: ...'evaling random strings is a bad idea'; it don't evals random strings, they don't pass test before eval takes place.

Comment: using dynamic values (arrays, null values, dates, etc.) in context where numbers are expected (like division, multiplication, subtraction, etc.) yields unexpected results.. just wanted to know if there is a rationale behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I don't really know what you're asking, I'll just answer everything.

### `n.valueOf`

([spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.4.4), [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/valueOf))

This call is done in case a number *object* (and not a number *primitive*) was passed to the function:

```
var numObj = new Number(4),
    numPrim = 4;

console.log(typeof numObj, typeof numPrim); //object, number
numObj === numPrim; //false
//however:
numObj.valueOf() === numPrim; //true
```

### `isFinite`

([spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.5), [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite))

`isFinite(arg)` converts `arg` to a number (I'll touch on how later), and checks if it's not one of NaN, +∞, or −∞:

```
isFinite(4); //true
isFinite(Infinity); //false
isFinite("Infinity"); //false (the argument is converted into a number)
isFinite("foobar"); //false (converting a random string to a number yields NaN
```

### `(1 / 0 === Math.abs(n))`

`1/0` brings us +∞, so this checks if the argument is +∞ or -∞. `Infinity` was caught in the `isFinite` call (notice how strange this is: `isFinite` was used as a trimming factor...but we still want `Infinity` to be a number).

### `(n + n === n)`

Again, this catches `Infinity`, as it's the only value to satisfy this equation (didn't check, but it makes sense; I'll talk about it in the end). Pretty useless, really.

### `eval(n) === parseFloat(Number(n))`

(parseFloat: [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.3), [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat))
(Number: [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.1.1), [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Syntax)).

This is an odd bunny. The reasoning behind it is beyond me. The left-hand side executes `n` as if it was js, and the right-hand converts `n` to a number. Twice. What this hopes to achieve is to probably catch `NaN` or an invalid number string.

It belongs in the Department of Redundancy Department for several reasons:

1. `Number` calls the internal `ToNumber` function, which converts the argument to a number based on js' syntax. Thus, if the argument was an invalid number, the return value would've been `NaN`. `eval` would've done the same thing at the end, but with greater overhead.
2. The outer call to `parseFloat` is ridiculous. `parseFloat` converts its argument to a string, and then tries to see if the string begins in a valid number. This was already done in `Number`, which is also more strict than `parseFloat` (as the former demands that the entire string be a valid number, not just the beginning).
3. `ToNumber` was already called in `isFinite`. If the argument was either `NaN` or a string which isn't a number, we would've gotten `false`.

So this function contains unneeded duplication and some illogical calls. Taken from [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/617762), it could be written as:

```
function isNumeric (n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

### On `ToNumber`

When you do `4 * []`, what happens ([section 11.5](http://es5.github.io/#x11.5)) is that each side of the operator is taken, converted to a number, and then the answer is calculated. How are they converted to a number? That's in [section 9.3, the `ToNumber` function](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3). In most cases where you see strange behaviour, it's because you use an object as one of the values to be operated on, and that object is converted into a string (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9032856/617762) for some examples).