# Strange Javascript return type

Tags: javascript

I tried the javascript codes below and I'm really confused about the result  , can anyone explain the result please .

```
 *  {} + [] return 0 

 *  [] + {} return Object
```

Comment: Provide console output please.

Comment: And better, more difficult to find: [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t. Are you watching Wat?

`{}` looks like a block in some REPLs. Use parentheses to make it work properly:

```
({} + []) // [object Object]
([] + {}) // [object Object]
```