# Are there special equality conditions relating to 0 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, equality

I have two samples of code that I don't understand why they evaluate the way they do

Sample one (these evaluate to true):

```
    {} + [] == 0
    {} + 1 == 1
    0/1 == 0
```

But then this will evaluate to NaN instead of 0:

```
    ({} + []) / ({} + 1)
```

---

Sample 2 (you can chain the first):

```
    1 == "1" == 1/1
```

But this will evaluate false even though choosing any two will evaluate true.

```
    0 == "0" == 0/1
```

Comment: Related https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: try the first set with '===' instead of '==' then go read up on the difference.

Comment: Another one for practice: `0==1==0`

Comment: `{} + []` is interpreted as `+[]`.  The `{}` is a "block", not an object.  `[]` is converted first to a string (`''`), then to a number (`0`).  It's not doing addition, it's the unary `+` operator.  Same with `{} + 1`.  When the `{}` is parenthesis, like in `({} + [])`, then it's treated as an object, and it becomes string concatenation (`'[object Object]' + ''`).

Comment: Try `0 == {}+[]` and `1 == {}+1` instead

Comment: @PeeHaa: As a JavaScript developer.... yep.

Answer (score 0):

You got explanations for first sample, so here is about second:

```
1 == "1" == 1/1 -> true
```

Explained: `1 == "1" -> true`, then `true == 1/1` evaluates to `1 == 1` which is `true`

```
0 == "0" == 0/1
```

Explained: `0 == "0" -> true`, then `true == 0/1` evaluates to `1 == 0` which is `false`

That is why my example `0 == 1 == 0` in the comments, evaluates to `true`.

`0 == 1 -> false`, `false == 0 -> true`

Answer (score 0):

> Sample one (these evaluate to true):
>
> ```
> {} + [] == 0
> {} + 1 == 1
> ```

Please understand [the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9032856/1048572) between your expressions and the following:

```
 ({} + []) == 0
 ({} + 1) == 1
```

Considering that the parenthesised expressions evaluate to `"[object Object]"` (and `"[object Object]1"` respectively), it will become clear why the division yields `NaN`.

---

Sample two is a different thing.

> Are there special equality conditions relating to 0 in javascript?

Yes. `0` is the only falsy number, which makes a difference when [comparing](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) with booleans (where `false` will be cast to `0`).

> ```
> 1 == "1" == 1/1
> ```

Check the evaluation of this:

```
(1 == "1") == 1/1 // casting the string to a number
(1 == 1) == 1
true == 1 // casting the boolean to a number
1 == 1
true
```

Since `1/1` is `1` and equality is commutative, the same holds for `1 == ("1" == 1/1)`

> But this will evaluate false even though choosing any two will evaluate true.
>
> ```
> 0 == "0" == 0/1
> ```

No "but":

```
(0 == "0") == 0/1 // again, casting the string to a number
(0 == 0) == 0
true == 0 // again, casting the boolean to a number
1 == 0
false
```

Again it doesn't matter whether we do `(0=="0)==0` or `0==("0"==0)`

Even without the typecasting, in plain boolean logic is clear that

```
(true == true) == true
```

will have a different result than

```
(false == false) == false
```

JavaScript does not support chained comparison operators, the operations will be implicitly nested. If you need to test three values for equality, do `(false == false) && (false == false)`.

Answer (score -1):

When you use the == operator you allow coercion.  That makes values either "truthy" or "falsy" depending on what operands are involved.  Try it with the === operator to see what happens.

Comment: as I hit enter on my comment I saw your answer crop up :P nice.

Comment: Using `===` for sample 1 won't make a difference actually

Comment: As might be true, but I'm trying to figure out why someone would compare either an empty object or empty array to 1.  Even in a loosely-typed language a programmer has to show some discipline--in fact, I'd say particularly in a loosely-typed language.