# Mysterious magic code, type casting

Tags: javascript

Why this piece of code returns 0

```
 a=!!function(){console.log(!0)}()+!!function(){console.log(!0)}()
```

and this one returns 2

```
 a=!!function(){}+!!function(){}
```

Whats the magic behind it?

**Edit:** 
This is what I would expect:
`function(){console.log(!0)}()` should return true because it was successful and it contains body. So when it is casted to boolean and then int it should be `1`

`function(){}` this should be false, since it is neither called nor contains function body. Same confusion with `!![]` and `!!""`

Comment: Is this a serious question? It's pretty obvious (the first two are IIFE and return nothing added together, the last two are functions cast as booleans added together)

Comment: @AD7six neither I am confused about the why it is the opposite way around then I would expect.

Comment: @AD7six I have edited my question with my expectations.

Comment: Much better though your expections are somewhat bizarre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1: `function(){}()` returns a `falsy` value.
  Then, `!!`, a double bitwise `not`, casts that to `false`.
  Result: `false + false === 0`.
- 2: `function(){}` is a `truthy` value.
  Then, `!!`, a double bitwise `not`, casts that to `true`.
  Result: `true + true === 2`.

The content of those functions are irrelevant in this question. The first line contains [IIFE's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) that return nothing, which is `falsy`.
The second line simply casts the 2 functions to booleans.

Now, when those booleans are converted to numbers (Due to the [`+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29)), this is the result:

```
Number(true)  // 1
Number(false) // 0
```

Comment: So if an empty anonymous function is cast to boolean it will always be true and when a function without return statement is invoked(successfully) will return false? Who designed it this way?

Comment: @Dharman: Yea, that's pretty much how it works. As for who designed it, it's a bit of a history lesson. The [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) has some more info

Comment: I would like some more explanation on why is that `falsy` and `truthy`.

Comment: @Dharman: The first function doesn't have a `return` statement, so returns `undefined`, which is, as to be expected, `falsy`.
The second statement tries to cast a function to a boolean value. Since a function is not part of the [list of "things" defined to be `falsy`](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/), it's cast to `true`.

Answer (score -1):

Both function are assigning to a the following value

```
 a=!!function(){console.log(!0)}()+!!function(){console.log(!0)}()
```

**!!function(){console.log(!0)}()**

- function(){console.log(!0)}() *=> function statement requires a name*
- !function(){console.log(!0)}() *=> return true (previously it was false)*
- !!function(){console.log(!0)}() *=> return false*

In javascript

```
false + false = 0
```

**Regarding the second function**

```
 a=!!function(){}+!!function(){}
```

**!!function(){}**

- function(){} => function statement requires a name
- !function(){} => false
- !! function(){} = true

In javascript

```
 true + true = 2
```

That's why you get 2

Comment: _"function statement requires a name"_: Nope, IIFE's don't. Nor do anonymous functions passed as parameters, for example. Also, you're not explaining _why_ those functions are `true` or `false`.

Comment: Arguably this is a better structured answer than the other- but it's factually wrong, and doesn't actually answer the (dubious) question. -1.

Comment: @AD7six Why is it wrong ? I just forgot to talk about this let you cast your function to do some tests

Comment: I know you cant assign a function to a var, or create anonymouse function used massivly for callback or stacking, but this express ''function(){}'' executed behind a braquet expression return the following error, it is not a definition

Comment: You _can_ assign a function to a variable (e.g. jQuery makes $ _a function_). You _can_ create anonymightymouse functions (very common). Im not sure what the last part of the above comment means - perhaps find some docs on immediately-invoked-function-expressions.

Answer (score -1):

The "magic" is that you apply the functions in the first case, and you don't apply them in the second case (that's the extra pair of () ).

So

```
var x = function(){console.log(!0)}
x;     // => function (){console.log(!0)}
x();   // => false
!!x(); // => false
!!x()+!!x() // => false + false => 0
```

whereas

```
var y = function(){};
y;       // => function () {};
!!y;     // => true
!!y+!!y; // => true + true => 2
```

note that if you *dont* call the function in the first case, you get the same thing:

```
var x = function(){console.log(!0)}
x;      // => function (){console.log(!0)}
!!x;    // => true
!!x+!!x // => true + true => 0
```

Now, of course, the reason behind the conversions (why is !!x - "the opposite of the opposite of a function" - "false", rather than "true", or 42, or NaN, or NotABoolean, or FileNotFound) falls into the ["Wat ??"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the?rq=1) category that is very common in Javascript.

Please *never* write this kind of code in real code that I'm ever likely to read, edit, or use.

Comment: `x() // => true` I'm guessing you're looking in the console - you're misreading the output, and if unedited the answer is wrong/misleading. x returns undefined. There is no WTF here. After edit: it's still wrong.

Comment: Yes, I miscopied. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry but your answer has caused me more confusion than the question itself

Comment: Sorry about that. I hope other answers will help you more.