# Why does "1" - - "1" return 2?

Tags: javascript

Why does `alert("1" - - "1")` return 2?

I'm not entirely sure what is going on here to create the result as 2?

I came across the problem here:
http://davidshariff.com/js-quiz

Comment: Post more info this is not enough to go on...

Comment: 1 - (-1) = 2 same as 1 + 1...

Comment: `"1"- -"1" = 1- -1 = 1-(-1) = 1+1 = 2`

Comment: This is unsurprising. What were you expecting exactly?

Comment: "one minus negative one"

Comment: I know this is a duplicate, but I can't find the older one.

Comment: What would you expect it to be instead?

Comment: prefix unary `-` tries to convert its operand to a number. That results in `-1`. If you subtract -1 from 1, again, the binary infix `-` operator will try to convert its argument as well, so you end up with `1 - (-1)` which is 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's like writing 1 - (-1) which is 1 + 1 = 2

the problem in js is that if you use + between 2 string it means concating them thus resulting 11

EDIT: thanks to iamnotmaynard comment i was able to find this post

[Why does JavaScript handle the plus and minus operators between strings and numbers differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383788/why-does-javascript-handle-the-plus-and-minus-operators-between-strings-and-numb)

Comment: This only answers part of the question. There is also confusion about type coercion.

Comment: When you use the "-" infix, javascript assumes that both of the arguments are numbers. For every other data type this operation does not make any sense. So if it is a string it tries to parse it as a number. You can try "test" - "something". This will return NaN.