# Meteor.js the plus operator

Tags: math, operator-keyword

I'm writing a simple program to teach the basic of input, form and template and sessions using Meteor.

```
 if (Meteor.isClient) {

 Session.set('value',0);


 Template.hello.helpers({

 result: function(){

  return(Session.get('value'));
}
});


Template.hello.events({

 'submit form': function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var s1=event.target.num1.value;
  var s2=event.target.num2.value;

  var s = s1 - s2;

 Session.set('value',s);

}
```

});
}

The problem is when the operator is changed to + it seems to concatenate the two numbers.  Other basic operators work fine. It is a bug ? This is the simplest example I can teach to my students and I get stuck.

I'm using Mac 10.6.8 and Meteor 1.1.0.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does JavaScript handle the plus and minus operators between strings and numbers differently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383788/why-does-javascript-handle-the-plus-and-minus-operators-between-strings-and-numb) // absolutely not meteor-specific btw.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing a JSFiddle but I bet you the problem is that one of the values or both is being passed in as a string.

The plus sign is the concatenation operator for JS and will perform type coercion from a number to a string, if both are not numbers and one is a string. The - operator will perform it the other way, and turn strings into numbers.

Check the data types being passed in and makes sure they're both numbers. If they aren't, use `parseInt` to turn them into numbers.

Answer (score 0):

string + string = string.

Try this:

```
  var s1=+event.target.num1.value;
  var s2=+event.target.num2.value;
```

Always turn your strings to numbers when you take them from the DOM.