# Working of the console.log and type of operator in javascript with example of type casting in javascript

Tags: javascript

In javascript if we did `console.log(1+'1'-1)` then we get 10 which is string. But if we did `typeof(1+'1'-1)` then we get number. Why??

Comment: This has nothing to do with `console.log`. It's type coercion in JS. Google that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does JavaScript handle the plus and minus operators between strings and numbers differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383788/why-does-javascript-handle-the-plus-and-minus-operators-between-strings-and-numb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does JavaScript handle the plus and minus operators between strings and numbers differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383788/why-does-javascript-handle-the-plus-and-minus-operators-between-strings-and-numb)

Comment: ...but I'd already voted to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future, as the premise of the question is an error. The 10 in the first example is not a string, it's a number.

Answer (score 2):

> In javascript if we did console.log(1+'1'-1) then we get 10 which is
>   string.

No, it's not a `string`. When you're using `-` operator both operands are *coerced* to `Number`. Hence, the type of the result is `Number`.

Comment: If this is a Number how the answer is 10 it should be 1+0=1 not 10??

Comment: 1+`1` is `11` then we substract 1 and the result is `10` which is `Number`

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut this has to be a joke right :D thank god I've never worked with JS, but what sense does it make to have `x + 'a' = xa` when `x` is a number and `a` a character?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow, This is how Js works when you're trying to concat string with a number the result is automatically coerced to `string`.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut that's a horrible concept imo. Anyways, thank you for giving clarification.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow, don't forget that javascript it's a weakly-typed language.  Also, there are many strange things in Javascript :). In this case, was just a simple rule as a said in my answer.