# JavaScript: Why would "1" - "1" return 0?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I was trying to subtract the last digit out of a string after a loop, but then I found this mysterious phenomenon.

When I add two string of numbers, they concatenate:

```js
"1" + "1" // = "11"
```

But when I subtract a string of number from another, it did not decatenate but was casted as a number instead:

```js
"11" - "1" // = 10
```

Why does this happen? 
Should the result of the subtraction be "1" instead of 10?
Wouldn't having some kind of consistency be better?

---

Edit: This question is NOT a duplicate of the question below, as this question is asking about the subtraction of two strings, instead of a string with a number.

[Why does JavaScript handle the plus and minus operators between strings and numbers differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383788/why-does-javascript-handle-the-plus-and-minus-operators-between-strings-and-numb)

Comment: That's the way the language works, like it or not. The `-` operator coerces its operands to numbers.

Comment: And what would you expect `"101" - "1"` to do? `"100"` or `"001"`? And what about `"010" - "1"`? Or `"200" - "1"`?

Comment: From what I understood, he expects string subtraction to work similar to a.replace(b, "")

Comment: Re edit. It **is** a duplicate. The accepted answer even says "You cannot perform subtraction on strings" which **completely** applies in the slightly-different-in-an-non-significant-way that this question poses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The subtraction operator (-) subtracts the number to the right of the
>   operator from the number on the left.
>
> When either of the operands are strings, an attempt is made to convert
>   the strings to numbers.

[Source](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0040__Operators/Subtraction.htm)