# new Date returned invalid in safari but chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, datetime, ecmascript-6, safari

new Date('2020-08-18 07:52') is working in Chrome, it returned

```
Tue Aug 18 2020 07:52:00 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)
```

but safari gave me invalid date? what's the best way to fix this? this bug in safari is breaking my entire app.

Comment: If I remember, Safari supports only [ISO 8601 date format](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

Comment: @AdamAzad I don't have control over the date string, it come from an api. what should I do?

Comment: I would do this: `\`${'2020-08-18 07:52'.replace(' ', 'T')}:00\``

Comment: @AdamAzad—and you'll still get differences between Safari and others. :-(

Comment: That format is not supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. Safari treats it as invalid (likely as a malformed version of a supported format), others don't. The fix is to parse it manually with a simple function or library.

Answer (score 0):

without need for tools/plugins/packages, I would simply separate the received date:

```js
var apiDate = '2020-08-18 07:52'
var [ date, time ] = apiDate.split(' ')
var [ year, month, day ] = date.split('-')
var [ hour, minute ] = time.split(':')

var newDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, 0)

// Tue Aug 18 2020 07:52:00
```

I would just be careful about TimeZones, as your date has no time zone description ...

**Note**
from the code above, one might think that [subtracting 1 from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24383847/28004) is invalid, but that's the caveats of javascript...

```js
"08" + 1 = "081"
"08" - 1 = 7
```

---

if the format is always the same, you can also do:

```js
var apiDate = '2020-08-18 07:52'

var newDate = new Date(`${apiDate.replace(' ', 'T')}:00`)  // '2020-08-18T07:52:00'

// Tue Aug 18 2020 07:52:00
```