# Javascript "+" and "-" operators behavior and usage

Tags: javascript

I want to find out why "+" and "-" operators behave differently in similar usage. And the usage convention for these operators.

An abstract example:

There are two different arrays, for simplicity, each have one number element.

To add or subtract the two elements from the different arrays, simply "+" and "-" by indexing them:

```
const arr1 = [1];
const arr2 = [2];

console.log(arr1[0] + arr2[0]); // 3
console.log(arr1[0] - arr2[0]); // -1
```

*... all good*

Now, for whatever reasons, try subtract them without indexing (given both only have one element each):

```
console.log(arr1 - arr2); // -1
```

*... ok*

Then, try to "add" them:

```
console.log(arr1 + arr2); // 12
```

*wait ... concatenated?*

Guess there's some kind of type conversion happening because when I use unary plus to ensure they are integers, it worked similar to subtraction:

```
console.log(+arr1 + +arr2); // 3
```

Aside: This question came about when I was working with Regex, an abstract example:

```
console.log("findthe1number".match(/\d/) + "findthenumber2".match(/\d/)); 
//12 concatenated

console.log("findthe1number".match(/\d/) - "findthenumber2".match(/\d/)); 
//-1 arithmetic
```

What I am keen to find out:

- Confirm that when "+" is used with certain types, it'll automatically convert and apply concatenation.
- If need to use '+' in cases similar to above, is forcing operands to integers the way to go

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does JavaScript handle the plus and minus operators between strings and numbers differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383788/why-does-javascript-handle-the-plus-and-minus-operators-between-strings-and-numb); particularly references to the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator).

Comment: It's all in the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/)...

Comment: [wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)?

Comment: @SebastianSimon cheers for the link. It really helps to confirm and explain in details. Appreciate it! Will refine my research keywords in the future.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen. Thanks for the link to the docs. Helps with diving in under the hood. Will give the docs a good try, some light reading.

Comment: @Theraot, LOL thanks for the link. A good laugh, Watman! Now, I can keep in mind the weird parts of the language.