# JavaScript variable - need an answer for this with some explanations

Tags: javascript, variables

const a = 2 + 3 + "4";

const b = "4" + 2 + 3;

console.log(a);  //return 54

console.log(b);  //return 423
how this happen??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computation is being done left to right.

```
const a = 2 + 3 + "4";
```

Left to right, 2 + 3 is done first. Becomes 5. 5 + "4" becomes "54" because "4" is a string.

```
const b = "4" + 2 + 3;
```

Left to right, we are starting with a string so "4" + 2 becomes "42". "42" + 3 becomes "423".

One with strings is string concatenation, and one with numbers is addition.

Note: I have mentioned string values inside `""`.

Comment: Now, I understand properly. Thank you so much

Comment: Sure please use the green tick to accept the answer, completing the question

Comment: To elaborate on, check this cases: `const a = 1 + "2";` and `const b = "1" + 2;`. Value for both constants is (string) "12". More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383788) and [here](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html).