# JavaScript += not incrementing correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that I'm trying to fade text into.

```js
function fadeIn(divNum) {
    let id = null;
    fadeDiv = document.getElementById("jsTest");
    fadeDiv.innerHTML = "";
    console.log(fadeDiv.style.opacity);
    if (divNum == 1) {
        fadeDiv.innerHTML = "some text";
    } else if (divNum == 2 ) {
        fadeDiv.innerHTML = "some different text";
    } else if (divNum == 3) {
        fadeDiv.innerHTML = "still different text";
    } else {
        fadeDiv.innerHTML = "Oops! that wasn't supposed to happen";
    }
    clearInterval(id);
    id = setInterval(moveIt,100);
    function moveIt() {
        if (fadeDiv.style.opacity == 1) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            fadeDiv.style.opacity += 0.1;
            console.log(fadeDiv.style.opacity);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="opacity: 0;" id="jsTest"></div>
<button class="boxButtonsb" onmouseover="fadeIn(1)">JavaScript Test</button>
```

When I mouseover, the opacity only reduces by `.1`, and looks like it just loops there forever. The `console.log` shows endless `0.1` entries.

But, if I reverse this, so the initial opacity is 1, there's text in the div to start, and I set `fadeIn` to actually fade out, by using `fadeDiv.style.opacity == 0` as the if statement check for `clearInterfal(id)`, and decrementing `fadeDiv.style.opacity` via `-= 0.1`, it works correctly.

I've zero idea why the decrement is working correctly, and the increment is not.

Comment: fadeDiv.style.opacity is a string '0'.1', '0.1' + 0.1 give string '0.10.1', which is incorrect value for opacity, and so it is not set; with "-" operator the js will convert string to number at first

Comment: Also related, as to why the decrement is working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24383788/why-does-javascript-handle-the-plus-and-minus-operators-between-strings-and-numb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTMLELement::style` contains string values, needs to be converted to a float:

```js
function fadeIn(divNum) {
    let id = null;
    fadeDiv = document.getElementById("jsTest");
    fadeDiv.innerHTML = "";
    console.log(fadeDiv.style.opacity);
    if (divNum == 1) {
        fadeDiv.innerHTML = "some text";
    } else if (divNum == 2 ) {
        fadeDiv.innerHTML = "some different text";
    } else if (divNum == 3) {
        fadeDiv.innerHTML = "still different text";
    } else {
        fadeDiv.innerHTML = "Oops! that wasn't supposed to happen";
    }
    clearInterval(id);
    id = setInterval(moveIt,100);
    function moveIt() {
        if (fadeDiv.style.opacity == 1) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            fadeDiv.style.opacity = +fadeDiv.style.opacity + .1;
            console.log(fadeDiv.style.opacity);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="opacity: 0;" id="jsTest"></div>
<button class="boxButtonsb" onmouseover="fadeIn(1)">JavaScript Test</button>
```

Comment: Alex, that did the trick, thank you so much. Everyone thanks for the explanation of why one was working and the other wasn't, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

CSS attributes are always strings, not numbers. Your code is doing `'0.1' + 0.1` which results in `'0.10.1'` which isn't a valid number, so it's probably getting truncated back to `0.1`.

One way to change it is to parse the result into a number.

```
        if (parseFloat(fadeDiv.style.opacity) == 1) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            fadeDiv.style.opacity = parseFloat(fadeDiv.style.opacity) + 0.1;
            console.log(fadeDiv.style.opacity);
        }
```