# Why summation of array & a object([ ] + {} ) is a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can some one please let me know why an addition of an empty object and an array  is a `string` in javascript

```
[ ] + [ ] = string
[ ] + { } = string
{ } + [ ] = [object Object]
{ } + { } = [object Object][object Object]
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/pr4aser5/)

Comment: You can find most of the well explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the

Comment: @ema you can mark this as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `+` operator tries to convert to number or string, which ever is common type.

`[].toString()` will return `""`, but `{}.toString()` will return `[object Object]`

```js
console.log([].toString())
console.log({}.toString())
```