# Why is null+null = 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript, null

I was doing some test for fun when noticed `null+null` is equal to `0`in javascript.
Is there any reason for it ?

Comment: Operands of the `+` operator are casted to numbers, unless they aren't strings

Comment: @hindmost  not always, but close enough

Comment: @hindmost null+[] is actually "null". I'd say it's pretty much standarized arbitrarly

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `+` operator works only with numbers and strings. When presented with something that isn't a number or a string, it coerces. The rules are [covered by the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-addition-operator-plus), but the short version is that the operands are [coerced to primitives](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-toprimitive) (which changes nothing in this particular case, `null` is a primitive) and then if either is a string, the other is coerced to string and concatenation is done; if neither is a string, both are coerced to numbers and addition is done.

So `null` gets [coerced to a number](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-tonumber). The specification dictates that `null` becomes `0`, so you get `0+0` which is of course `0`.

---

If anyone's curious about David Haim's [`null+[]` is `"null"` observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315250/why-is-nullnull-0-in-javascript/39315286#comment65962742_39315250), that happens because of that coercion-to-primitive thing I mentioned: The empty array `[]` is coerced to a primitive. When you coerce an array to a primitive, it ends up calling `toString()`, which calls `join()`. `[].join()` is `""` because there are no elements. So it's `null+""`. So `null` is coerced to *string* instead of number, giving us `"null"+""` which is of course `"null"`.