# Why the Sum of Null and zero is zero

Tags: javascript, null

We all know the difference between `null` and `zero`.
**ZERO**
"Zero" is a value. It is the unique, known quantity of zero, which is meaningful in arithmetic and other math.
**Null**
"Null" is a non-value. It is a "placeholder" for a data value that is not known or not specified. mathematical operations cannot be performed on null.
Then how it is possible that

> [1, null+null]         --->         [1,0]
>      [1, null+1] ---> [1,1]

So here null undertaking zero as the default value and doing arithmetic operations.Is there any reason behind this operation.

Comment: `null` *is* a value. When converted to a number, it is converted to `0`: `Number(null)`.

Comment: `null` in JavaScript is not like the term that is used in other contexts, such as in databases.

Comment: `null + null = 0` implicit coercion to 0 on null values

Comment: On a similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the/9033306#9033306

Comment: It's curious inddeed that ToNumber(null) is +0 but ToNumber(undefined) is NaN