# why does ([]+![])[+!+[]] becomes a in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does this

> ([]+![])[+!+[]]

becomes

> a

in Javascript?

is there any link or some explanations about this?
any links would be great!

I've seen links as provided but, it only seems to answer the Numeric Part.
Yet, I cant seem to grasp as to why would these *([]+![])[+!+[]]* translates or equates to *a*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9032856/218196 and lots of other similar questions.

Comment: Ummm its a number(the link), but this one is about character. which is confusing, thanks for the link though @FelixKling

Comment: `![]` is `false`, `[]+false` becomes `""+false` and is `"false"`. `+[]` becomes `+""` and is `0`. `!0` is `true`, `+true` is `1` and `("false")[1]` is `"a"`

Comment: Figuring this out is unlikely to be of any use whatsoever to you or anyone else, unless you plan to participate in some JavaScript trivia competition.