# I want an explanation to this code: (4 + [] + 8)

Tags: javascript

When I execute

```js
console.log( (4 + [] + 8) )
```

I get the result of `48` and when I execute `[]` alone it gives `0`. How does it work?

Comment: its like `foo = null`, so `foo === null` and `typeof foo === 'object'`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @DarkMukke

Comment: When you execute `[]` alone, it gives you an empty array.

Comment: `[].toString()` is `""` - i.e. an empty join.  You will need to show how you get `0` from `[]` for an explanation.

Comment: `[]` with `+` (as a binary operator) will make it an empty string. So it basically becomes `4 + '' + 8` hence 48.

Comment: When you treat it an integer it gives the value (0) but when you use it in an expression like (4 + [] + 8) the value of this expression is (48) @rmalviya

Comment: Also see [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the)

Comment: Thank you guys now I got it @Alex K.

Comment: @MostafaElnaggar Give me an example of  treating `[]` as an integer. I was talking about last statement in your question.

Comment: `+[]` would be a number

Comment: @AlexK. He (@MostafaElnaggar) used word `alone`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this is a sum of a `number` and an `array`, javascript is converting both to strings.

Therefore:

`'4' + '' + '8' = '48'` (notice that the result is a `string`, not a `number`)

If you add more elements to the array, it will work like this

`4 + [1, 2] + 8 = '41,28'`

This happens because arrays, by default, become strings by concatenating values with `,`.

Another example

`4 + [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] + 8` = `41,2,3,4,58`

Note: If you try summing two `arrays` they will also become strings, as javascript doesn't have a native implementation for summing arrays.

`[1, 2] + [3, 4] = '1,23,4'`

Answer (score 0):

Like explained in the comments.
When you use the `+` operator on an array to a variable of a different type, the js engine will call it as a string via [].toString().
Adding a number to a string also converts the numbers to a string.

Comment: Should include an example vs. saying "like the comments"

Comment: You are right. but I did not want the credits, nor the upvotes, just get this more or less all over google question of the interesting page